# Why doesn't position: sticky work in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

How do you get `position: sticky` working?

I tried the following in Chrome 26.0.1410.43 m and it's not working:

```
thead {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8LRms/

According to this, it should work:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

It seemed to be supported in Chrome 23.0.1247.0, but now it doesn't work in 26.0.1410.43 m.

Comment: Did you go to the demo page on the link you posted? http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html  When I did, it told me that: Your browser does not support position: sticky!!

Comment: I have no idea if it was or wasn't... I am just pointing out that you have the answer right there, on the page you posted.

Comment: Well, I really don't mean to be a smart ass... but it does explain why it DOESN'T work.  It's because your browser doesn't support `position: sticky`.  I guess you would have to update your question to ask "Why did my browser support it in the past and no longer does now?"

Comment: @Steve question updated.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-sticky

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**EDIT**: You need to launch with `--enable-experimental-webkit-features` flag enabled via `about:flags`.

**Update:** This does not work on Chrome v35 through v51, Chrome 52 reenables this with the experimental web platform features flag. Starting from Chrome 56 `position: sticky` works out of the box.

Comment: This switch seems to make the demo from the html5rocks.com site work, but still fails on the jsFiddle.

Comment: It works with your `<h1>` just not with the `<thead>`. Either that type of element hasn't been added to the support yet, or it's not going to be possible. Changing the `thead` display to `block` or `inline-block` does nothing as well. Stick to naturally block or inline-block elements and you should be good.

Comment: I hope support for `<thead>` and `<tr>` becomes first class. Having a scrolling table with sticky headings and or section headings seems like a common use case.

Comment: Support for sticky positioning on thead elements USED TO work (and worked beautifully).  I noticed that it broke after a particular minor/patch release of Chrome 23, which I reported to one of the Chromium devs.  Why they yanked support is beyond me, since they had it working flawlessly.

Comment: @Aquarelle can you post the link to the ticket so we can harass the Chrome team? :P

Comment: The flag for this is now "Enable experimental Web Platform features." chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Comment: From MDN's position page: "The effect of ‘position: sticky’ on table elements is the same as for ‘position: relative’."

Comment: @Aquarelle it is now implemented in Blink and recognized without the -webkit prefix. Simply "position: sticky" works

Comment: @TaylorMac Thanks for the update.  However, I tested this again on Chrome v.35 and it didn't work (at least not for thead elements).  Also, caniuse.com states that support for this property will not appear in Chrome for the foreseeable future.  So, I'm not sure what to say.  From what I've read, some folks at Samsung have taken over the implementation of this in Chrome, and they're not ready yet (I get email updates about this specific issue on the Chromium bug tracker, which is how I know).  What I don't understand, though, is why support was ripped out when it used to work just fine.

Comment: @Aquarelle See my recent answer to detail a bit about why the feature was removed. tl;dr "It wasn't implemented well. Better to start over while it's still early"

Comment: Working again in v52 with the enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag enabled: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231752

Comment: for some reason `sticky` still isnt working for me, even with chrome 80 :/

Comment: nm i just realized you need a `top` value for it to work. duhhh

Answer (score 49):

For a short time, Chrome enabled this feature behind a flag, `--enable-experimental-webkit-features`, in their about:flags section. However, it was shortly removed due to inefficiencies in how the browser was repainting.

**As of [Chrome 56](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/12/chrome-56-beta-not-secure-warning-web.html), this feature is enabled without a flag once again.**

---

As of Chrome 52.0.2743.116, this feature is enabled by the flag `--enable-experimental-webkit-features` once more.

---

To answer the updated question about **why it was removed**: Google (Chromium) removed support for `position: sticky` due to the unfinished nature of the spec, and they will focus on other scrolling features in the mean-time:

> "We would eventually like to implement position: sticky, but **the current
>   implementation isn't designed in a way that integrates well with the existing
>   scrolling and compositing system**. For example, position: sticky relies upon
>   updateLayerPositionsAfterDocumentScroll to function correctly, but that
>   function has no other purpose and can otherwise be removed. Similarly,
>   position: sticky doesn't work at all with composited overflow scrolling, which
>   is now the default mechanism for driving scrolling in the engine.
>
> Once we've got our scrolling and compositing house in order, we should return
>   to position: sticky and **implement the feature in a way that integrates well
>   with the rest of the engine**. For now, however, this CL removes our current
>   implementation so we can focus on improving our implementation of the scrolling
>   features we've already shipped."

Emphasis mine. You can read more about it **[here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231752#c28)**.

Comment: I understood that the reason was that the implementation within the Chrome was poor enough that they scrapped the whole feature. As far as I know, the spec was okay. New implementation for Chrome is in progress: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6190250464378880

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen Yes, the spec is fine; multiple other browsers have had it implemented since before Chrome removed it from theirs. They're still working on it within the same "bug" on the tracker as they were when it was removed, though "in progress" is a lose term.

Comment: I understood that "Chromium [...] removed support [...] due to the unfinished nature of the spec" claimed that the spec was unfinished, which did not sound correct to me.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen That was their wording, sorry.

Comment: Working again in v52 with the enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag enabled: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231752

Comment: @franzo \o/ hallelujah

Answer (score 12):

FilamentGroup released a nice polyfill for `position: sticky`. Have a look at: https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky

Answer (score 10):

It seems that it doesn't work on iOS7 Safari if there is a parent node with `overflow: hidden` property set.

Comment: Could you add a reference or other evidence?

Comment: I do confirm that this is a problem on IOS7, load up the iFrame src in mobile safari to test: http://jsfiddle.net/C4uBE/2/

Comment: Great catch - this is the case in both Chrome 54 and Firefox 51

Comment: It doesn't stop working. The position is just being calculated relative to the element with `overflow`, rather that the viewport.

Answer (score 4):

It does - now at least
Look up https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

You are targeting the `<thead>` while Chrome and the Blink engine(Chrome, Edge, Opera) does not support this. Gecko(Mozilla Firefox) and Webkit(Safari) does. Instead try to target the `<th>` instead as shown below.

Also `overflow: hidden` on a parent WILL break `position:sticky`

Be sure to include your [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Run the snippet and it should show a functional sticky header.

```css
thead > tr > th {
    background: white;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Position sticky</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
            <th>column 4</th>            
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

When Chrome switched over to the Blink rendering engine with version 28, they dropped Webkit, which is the only engine to support this (on Mac and iOS.)

So unless you're using Safari on Mac or iOS, or Chrome on iOS (for now) you will not be able to support this in other browsers.

Sad, it's a great and easy way to float elements.

Comment: Indeed, it was a great way to float elements, specially in tables that you need to keep the `thead` fixed and scroll the `tbody`, I wonder if chrome is gonna bring it back, but for now, we still need to use "dirty solutions" :/

Answer (score 1):

**The [great news](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/position-stickyhttp://) is that as of Chrome 56 (currently beta as of December 2016, stable in Jan 2017) position: sticky is now back in Chrome.**
So, in the near future only Edge would be the only one of all browsers that hasn't implemented it still, except browsers for mobile devices, but I hope they would implement it also soon.

Comment: @Tricksfortheweb Chrome for Android currently supports it too