# Event to detect when position:sticky is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I'm using the new `position: sticky` ([info](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)) to create an iOS-like list of content.

It's working well and far superior than the previous JavaScript alternative ([example](http://jsbin.com/omanut/2/edit)) however as far as I know no event is fired when it's triggered, which means I can't do anything when the bar hits the top of the page, unlike with the previous solution.

**I'd like to add a class (e.g. `stuck`) when an element with `position: sticky` hits the top of the page. Is there a way to listen for this with JavaScript? Usage of jQuery is fine.**

Comment: It's funny because the top rated comment on that article solves your problem exactly. That guy got it spot on, this should be a media query, not a property. That way you could alter styles when the element gets stuck (which we often do). Oh well, a man can dream.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that comment, his proposal seems far better. Still, `position: sticky` is what Chrome's implemented so I'm looking for a way to make it usable!

Comment: If anyone gets here via Google one of their own engineers has a solution using IntersectionObserver, custom events, and sentinels: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers

Comment: Am I dumb?! What article is the first commenter talking about?!

Comment: @katerlouis No! I think it's a case of link rot, or comment removal.

Answer (score 148):

## [Demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/bGbmqZe?editors=0110) with [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) (use a trick):

```js
// get the sticky element
const stickyElm = document.querySelector('header')

const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle('isSticky', e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  {threshold: [1]}
);

observer.observe(stickyElm)
```

```css
body{ height: 200vh; font:20px Arial; }

section{
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 2em 1em;
}

header{
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;                       /* ➜ the trick */

  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: calc(1em + 1px);    /* ➜ compensate for the trick */

  background: salmon;
  transition: .1s;
}

/* styles for when the header is in sticky mode */
header.isSticky{
  font-size: .8em;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<section>Space</section>
<header>Sticky Header</header>
```

The `top` value needs to be `-1px` or the element will never intersect with the top of the browser window (thus never triggering the *intersection observer*).

To counter this `1px` of hidden content, an additional `1px` of space should be added to either the border or the padding of the sticky element.

Alternatively, if you wish to keep the CSS as is (`top:0`), then you can apply the "correction" at the *intersection observer*-level by adding the setting `rootMargin: '-1px 0px 0px 0px'` (as *@mattrick* showed in his answer)

## Demo with old-fashioned `scroll` event listener:

1. [auto-detecting first scrollable parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35939886/104380)
2. [Throttling the scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27078285/104380)
3. Functional composition for concerns-separation
4. Event callback caching: `scrollCallback` (to be able to unbind if needed)

```js
// get the sticky element
const stickyElm = document.querySelector('header');

// get the first parent element which is scrollable
const stickyElmScrollableParent = getScrollParent(stickyElm);

// save the original offsetTop. when this changes, it means stickiness has begun.
stickyElm._originalOffsetTop = stickyElm.offsetTop;


// compare previous scrollTop to current one
const detectStickiness = (elm, cb) => () => cb & cb(elm.offsetTop != elm._originalOffsetTop)

// Act if sticky or not
const onSticky = isSticky => {
   console.clear()
   console.log(isSticky)
   
   stickyElm.classList.toggle('isSticky', isSticky)
}

// bind a scroll event listener on the scrollable parent (whatever it is)
// in this exmaple I am throttling the "scroll" event for performance reasons.
// I also use functional composition to diffrentiate between the detection function and
// the function which acts uppon the detected information (stickiness)

const scrollCallback = throttle(detectStickiness(stickyElm, onSticky), 100)
stickyElmScrollableParent.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCallback)



// OPTIONAL CODE BELOW ///////////////////

// find-first-scrollable-parent
// Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42543908/104380
function getScrollParent(element, includeHidden) {
    var style = getComputedStyle(element),
        excludeStaticParent = style.position === "absolute",
        overflowRegex = includeHidden ? /(auto|scroll|hidden)/ : /(auto|scroll)/;

    if (style.position !== "fixed") 
      for (var parent = element; (parent = parent.parentElement); ){
          style = getComputedStyle(parent);
          if (excludeStaticParent && style.position === "static") 
              continue;
          if (overflowRegex.test(style.overflow + style.overflowY + style.overflowX)) 
            return parent;
      }

    return window
}

// Throttle
// Credit: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/m7G64
function throttle (callback, limit) {
    var wait = false;                  // Initially, we're not waiting
    return function () {               // We return a throttled function
        if (!wait) {                   // If we're not waiting
            callback.call();           // Execute users function
            wait = true;               // Prevent future invocations
            setTimeout(function () {   // After a period of time
                wait = false;          // And allow future invocations
            }, limit);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
header{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;

  /* not important styles */
  background: salmon;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: .1s;
}

header.isSticky{
  /* styles for when the header is in sticky mode */
  font-size: .8em;
  opacity: .5;
}

/* not important styles*/

body{ height: 200vh; font:20px Arial; }

section{
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<section>Space</section>
<header>Sticky Header</header>
```

---

### Here's a [React component demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/bGbmqZe?editors=0110) which uses the first technique

Comment: Why is the "trick" needed? What happens if you use `top: 0` and `padding-top: 1em`?

Comment: @DanielTonon - From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/intersectionRatio) ▶ "*intersectionRatio property tells you how much of the target element is currently visible within the root's intersection ratio, as a value between 0.0 and 1.0.*" ▶ Only `top` property will offset the element, thus making sure it will never be 100% visible (less than `1`)

Comment: Ok right, if you set `top: 0` then it will never intersect with the top of the browser window. Setting `top: -1px` will allow for `1px` worth of intersection (though `1px` worth of the content will not be visible thus the need to compensate for the trick). Clever 

Comment: You could avoid the calc function by using `border-top: 1px solid transparent` instead.

Comment: I made some edits. I clarified what the "trick" was and why it was needed. I also clarified for people what parts of the CSS were required vs what was superfluous (I was thinking of deleting the unnecessary stuff for clarity). Lastly making the "demo" word a link makes it easier for people to access in a more intuitive way than scrolling all the way to the end of the answer to access the live demo. All of these things make the answer more useful to people.

Comment: I compress my scripts with Grunt Uglify, and Grunt doesn't grok newer JS code styles.  I've added an Answer, below, that shows a modified version of this script, that will work properly with Grunt Uglify.

Comment: @StephenR nobody uses Grunt anymore since 2015 ‎

Comment: How will this work if top already has a positive value?

Comment: @BritishSam - use `transform` instead to position it from the top then. or `margin`.

Comment: Just an FYI that the React hook in the demo uses `createRef()` when it should instead (ideally) use `useRef`.

Comment: The problem with this is that isSticky is also applied if the element is out of view further down the page. This can cause issues and flashes of content if you're relying on the class to show/hide stuff on scroll.

Comment: Solved as follows: `e.target.classList.toggle('isSticky', e.boundingClientRect.top < 0)`

Comment: Why are you using `height: 200vh;` in your `body`?

Comment: @MauricioBetancurMolina - to make sure a scrollbar will be rendered in the demo

Comment: FYI, the demo "alternate" method using rootMargin doesn't seem to work

Comment: Unfortunately, `IntersectionObserver` method does not always toggle class or attribute properly – it happens during fast scrolling. At least I have this issue using Chrome.

Comment: @Ryba - [Report it as a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) then with reproducible minimal demo.

Comment: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61115077/1341949), you can just set [the IntersectionObserver's `rootMargin` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin) to `-1px 0 0 0` to get around the `top:-1px` offset hack!

Comment: @RafeGoldberg - It's mentioned in my answer, in the  part (year before the answer you linked to)

Answer (score 67):

I found a solution somewhat similar to @vsync's answer, but it doesn't require the "hack" that you need to add to your stylesheets. You can simply change the boundaries of the IntersectionObserver to avoid needing to move the element itself outside of the viewport:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  rootMargin: '-1px 0px 0px 0px',
  threshold: [1],
});

observer.observe(element);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? This does not seem to work for me.

Comment: most elegant answer imho

Comment: This works when my sticky is on the right but it doesn't work when the sticky element is on the left (horizontally scrolled, obviously with adjusted rootMargins). When it is on the left, it is always intersecting so I can never determine when it sticks. Root margin makes no difference.

Comment: mixed with vsync response; works perfect :)

Comment: Hi, it works, but as this requires much more code, and since the `top` CSS property has to be written anyway, then it's much shorter to simply change `top:0` to `top:-1` and call it a day ;) unless this small CSS change causes some visual bug in your design

Comment: I needed to do the same but the header behaves at sticky viewport + some top property. can someone help me how to achieve that. Detailed SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72158078/intersectionobserver-toggle-a-class-when-sticky-element-intersects-with-viewpo

Comment: @vsync `top:-1` doesn't mean anything in modern CSS. Did you mean `top: -1px` or something else?

Comment: Note that the 2nd parameter for IntersectionObserver() constructor should also define the `root` property. You can use `null` for the viewport or any *ancestor* element if you want to compute intersection against that one. If you pass a non-ancestor element, you will not get any errors but the callback is never called.

Comment: Yes my meaning was `-1px`

Comment: Here's a demo for this technique: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-detect-when-a-sticky-element-gets-pinned/ – This demo doesn't use `rootMargin` so it's off-by-one pixel.

Comment: This answer will not work for an element that is flush to the top of the page.  For example, a navbar.  It will always be considered activated.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this very simply like so:

1. Attach a scroll event listener
2. Get the desired sticky `top` position of the element via [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
3. Get the current viewport offset of the element using [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)
4. Add the class if both values match using [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

Here's how it looks like in code:

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".my-sticky-element");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const stickyTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).top);
    const currentTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    el.classList.toggle("is-sticky", currentTop === stickyTop);
});
```

Comment: super simple / elegant solution

Comment: This is indeed a correct and simple solution to the problem. One thing I'd add is checking if the element has been scrolled past:

`el.getBoundingClientRect().top <= parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).top, 10)`

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution that works like a charm and is pretty small. :)

No extra elements needed.

It does run on the window scroll event though which is a small downside.

```js
apply_stickies()

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    apply_stickies()
})

function apply_stickies() {
    var _$stickies = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.sticky'))
    _$stickies.forEach(function(_$sticky) {
        if (CSS.supports && CSS.supports('position', 'sticky')) {
            apply_sticky_class(_$sticky)
        }
    })
}

function apply_sticky_class(_$sticky) {
    var currentOffset = _$sticky.getBoundingClientRect().top
    var stickyOffset = parseInt(getComputedStyle(_$sticky).top.replace('px', ''))
    var isStuck = currentOffset <= stickyOffset

    _$sticky.classList.toggle('js-is-sticky', isStuck)
}
```

Note: This solution doesn't take elements that have bottom stickiness into account. This only works for things like a sticky header. It can probably be adapted to take bottom stickiness into account though.

Comment: Great answer. The answer put forward by Google is good, but it's overkill for most purposes. Plus this has IE11 support.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it IE11 support. It's more like it just won't cause the site to crash if viewed in IE11. IE11 doesn't support `position: sticky`.

Comment: ▶ scroll event callback should probably be **throttled** since intense calculations  are being done there. Also, a developer would have to actively cleanup the event binding and re-bind on DOM changes, because sticky elements might be appended to the DOM *after** this function had run. Also.. this code is *far** from optimal and can be much refactored for performance & readability

Comment: It can't be throttled if you want a smooth transition. It doesn't seem to perform that badly in my experience. DOM elements *might* be appended. The vast majority of the time that isn't the case though. If you know a much better way to do the same thing then feel free to provide your own answer.

Comment: I've provided my own answer :)

Comment: I think it would be faster to do the forEach loop of the the _$stickies array inside of a single scroll listener, rather than creating a listener for each sticky.

Comment: Good point @Jordan, I've updated my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: Nice, one more optimization would be to only create the scroll listener if CSS.supports is true

Answer (score 2):

After Chrome added `position: sticky`, it was found to be [not ready enough](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152681) and [relegated to to --enable-experimental-webkit-features flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646747/css-position-sticky). Paul Irish [said in February](https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/243119987361980416) "feature is in a weird limbo state atm".

I was using [the polyfill](https://github.com/matthewp/position--sticky-) until it become too much of a headache. It works nicely when it does, but there are corner cases, like CORS problems, and it slows page loads by doing XHR requests for all your CSS links and reparsing them for the "position: sticky" declaration that the browser ignored.

Now I'm using [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed), which I like better than [StickyJS](http://stickyjs.com) because it doesn't mess up my layout with a wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no native solution. See [Targeting position:sticky elements that are currently in a 'stuck' state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308823/targeting-positionsticky-elements-that-are-currently-in-a-stuck-state). However I have a CoffeeScript solution that works with both native `position: sticky` and with polyfills that implement the sticky behavior.

Add 'sticky' class to elements you want to be sticky:

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

CoffeeScript to monitor 'sticky' element positions and add the 'stuck' class when they are in the 'sticky' state:

```
$ -> new StickyMonitor

class StickyMonitor

  SCROLL_ACTION_DELAY: 50

  constructor: ->
    $(window).scroll @scroll_handler if $('.sticky').length > 0

  scroll_handler: =>
    @scroll_timer ||= setTimeout(@scroll_handler_throttled, @SCROLL_ACTION_DELAY)

  scroll_handler_throttled: =>
    @scroll_timer = null
    @toggle_stuck_state_for_sticky_elements()

  toggle_stuck_state_for_sticky_elements: =>
    $('.sticky').each ->
      $(this).toggleClass('stuck', this.getBoundingClientRect().top - parseInt($(this).css('top')) <= 1)
```

NOTE: This code only works for vertical sticky position.

Comment: This solution has the advantage of (seeming to me to) coping with window resize and page reflow, unlike those that inspect and save `offsetTop`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been some time since the question was asked, but I found a good solution to this. The plugin [stickybits](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits) uses `position: sticky` where supported, and applies a class to the element when it is 'stuck'. I've used it recently with good results, and, at time of writing, it is active development (which is a plus for me) :)

Comment: One gotcha with stickybits is that I've found it doesn't work brilliantly when you have other js listening to scroll events. These issues only became apparent when I tested in a browser that didn't support `position: sticky` (ie11, edge).

Comment: This lib is buggy as ****

Comment: It has been forked and is maintained [here](https://github.com/yowainwright/stickybits), I quite like this option.

Answer (score 0):

Just use vanilla JS for it. You can use throttle function from lodash to prevent some performance issues as well.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("element-id");

document.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  _.throttle(e => {
    element.classList.toggle(
      "is-sticky",
      element.offsetTop <= window.scrollY
    );
  }, 500)
);
```

Comment: Using `_` is not exactly vanilla JS.

Comment: @SơnTrần-Nguyễn As I specified, it is a lodash function to prevent a possible performance issue

Comment: it should be `window.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this snippet in my theme to add `.is-stuck` class to `.site-header` when it is in a stuck position:

```
// noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
(function (document, window, undefined) {

    let windowScroll;

    /**
     *
     * @param element {HTMLElement|Window|Document}
     * @param event {string}
     * @param listener {function}
     * @returns {HTMLElement|Window|Document}
     */
    function addListener(element, event, listener) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(event, listener);
        } else {
            // noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
            if (element.attachEvent) {
                element.attachEvent('on' + event, listener);
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to attach event.');
            }
        }
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the element is in a sticky position.
     *
     * @param element {HTMLElement}
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function isSticky(element) {
        if ('sticky' !== getComputedStyle(element).position) {
            return false;
        }
        return (1 >= (element.getBoundingClientRect().top - parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).top)));
    }

    /**
     * Toggles is-stuck class if the element is in sticky position.
     *
     * @param element {HTMLElement}
     * @returns {HTMLElement}
     */
    function toggleSticky(element) {
        if (isSticky(element)) {
            element.classList.add('is-stuck');
        } else {
            element.classList.remove('is-stuck');
        }
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Toggles stuck state for sticky header.
     */
    function toggleStickyHeader() {
        toggleSticky(document.querySelector('.site-header'));
    }

    /**
     * Listen to window scroll.
     */
    addListener(window, 'scroll', function () {
        clearTimeout(windowScroll);
        windowScroll = setTimeout(toggleStickyHeader, 50);
    });

    /**
     * Check if the header is not stuck already.
     */
    toggleStickyHeader();


})(document, window);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

@vsync 's excellent answer was almost what I needed, except I "uglify" my code via Grunt, and Grunt requires some older JavaScript code styles.  Here is the adjusted script I used instead:

```
var stickyElm = document.getElementById('header');
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (_ref) {
    var e = _ref[0];
    return e.target.classList.toggle('isSticky', e.intersectionRatio < 1);
}, {
    threshold: [1]
});
observer.observe( stickyElm );
```

The CSS from that answer is unchanged

Answer (score -2):

Something like this also works for a fixed scroll height:

```js
// select the header
const header = document.querySelector('header');
// add an event listener for scrolling
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  // add the 'stuck' class
  if (window.scrollY >= 80) navbar.classList.add('stuck');
  // remove the 'stuck' class
  else navbar.classList.remove('stuck');
});
```