# position:sticky : Adding style when the element detaches from normal flow

Tags: javascript, css

Let's take take a simple example:

```html
<nav id="#mynav">MY NAVBAR</nav>
```

and a basic style:

```css
#mynav {
    position : sticky;
}
```

I would like to apply the following styling information to my navbar **only** when it detaches from the normal flow, in order to visually split it from the main content (with a shadow in this case)

```css
box-shadow : 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Is there some kind of pseudo-class or media-query-like thing I could use for that? E.g.:

```css
#mynav:some-pseudo-class {
    box-shadow : 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

I know there are good plugins for this, but all of them seem to be unable to implement it whithout bypassing the (quite new) native feature `position:sticky`. Instead, they do it in an old-fashion way (scroll event, and `position:fixed; top:0`).

So, is it possible to do it using `position:sticky`, and without using the `scroll` event, which slows down the fluidity of the page (I'm not against javascript, but scroll event is too slow)?

Comment: This will help: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know there are no pseudo class that targets the 'sticky' state.

See post: [Targeting position:sticky elements that are currently in a 'stuck' state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308823/targeting-positionsticky-elements-that-are-currently-in-a-stuck-state)

An alternative would be to use jQuery to add or remove a class/css styling when it reaches the element that needs to be stickied.

Comment: @Yako If you check the link I mentioned there are couple of JS code to choose from.

Comment: Just a quick note on browser support as the top comment is from 2017. Sticky is now well supported by browsers. ie11 is the only browser without support, and represents only 1% of global users at the time of writing. Sticky also degrades gracefully, so your best bet is to go for a css solution if it can fit your needs.

See https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer here https://css-tricks.com/how-to-detect-when-a-sticky-element-gets-pinned/

As of today you do need to use javascript:

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".myElement")
const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle("is-pinned", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  { threshold: [1] }
);

observer.observe(el);
```

```css
#parent { 
  height: 2000px; 
}

.myElement {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

/* styles for when the header is in sticky mode */
.myElement.is-pinned {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  
  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />
  <div class="myElement">Hello!</div>
  
</div>
```

`top: -1px` is very important because `IntersectionObserver` detect "how much your element is visible on the screen". `e.intersectionRatio` correspond to the percent of "visibility" of your `el`. So if you use `top: 0px` then `e.intersectionRatio` will always equal `1` and the class `is-pinned` will never be added.

Answer (score -1):

Your best solution is probably to rely on a JavaScript scroll event.  CSS has (limited) support for snap points, but that's the closest it has right now to any sort of scroll event support.

If your only concern with a JS solution is fluidity, I might suggest trying to apply CSS transitions to `#mynav` so that when the element is altered on scroll, there is a smoother visual cue that something is changing.

Answer (score -1):

**Using Jquery:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="elementSticky"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.elementSticky {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 background-color: blue;
}

.elementStickyScroll {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
 var currentPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
 var stickyElement = $('.elementSticky');
 
 
 if(currentPosition >= 1) {
    stickyElement.addClass('elementStickyScroll');
   }else {
    stickyElement.removeClass('elementStickyScroll');
   }
  });
 });
```