# Knowing when the position: sticky div is stuck without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a mobile first UI of an Angular project, where the div which is position: sticky needs to change its style, so how can I apply styling to the div only after it is stuck, without using jQuery, etc.

I've tried using https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver
but I am not able to mock that functionality

```css
.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
}


/*On being stuck*/

.title
/*::stuck*/

{
  font-size: 18px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 700px;">
  <div class="title" style="position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; top: 20px;">
    This div is to be styled on being 'stuck'
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're asking for a pseudo selector, it [isn't possible yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312347/4051471)

Comment: If you know how to do it with JQuery, you can use [this website](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) to convert it to plain JS

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    position = document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].style.position;
    result = position === 'sticky';
    console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is asking for this. `sticky` can have different behaviours according to scrolling, I guess he meant how to distinguish them

Comment: This logs false to console. Besides doesn't log 'sticky' on being sticky. Thank you tho. Any other workarounds?