# Simple throttle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, throttling

I am looking for a simple throttle in JavaScript. I know libraries like lodash and underscore have it, but only for one function it will be overkill to include any of those libraries.

I was also checking if jQuery has a similar function - could not find.

[I have found one working throttle](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls), and here is the code:

```
function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
  threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
  var last,
      deferTimer;
  return function () {
    var context = scope || this;

    var now = +new Date,
        args = arguments;
    if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
      // hold on to it
      clearTimeout(deferTimer);
      deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        last = now;
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, threshhold);
    } else {
      last = now;
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
```

The problem with this is: it fires the function once more after the throttle time is complete. So let's assume I made a throttle that fires every 10 seconds on keypress - if I do keypress 2 times, it will still fire the second keypress when 10 seconds are completed. I do not want this behavior.

Comment: 1. jQuery has a plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ 2. Why not just use underscore/lodash's throttle implementation?

Comment: @Oleg is it possible to use only the throttle without importing the whole lib?

Comment: Could you set up an example, or at least explain the use case a little better? Generally a keypress throttle is pretty simple to set up, something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/a3w6pLbj/1/**

Comment: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L754

Comment: If your bundler do not have [`tree-shaking` capabilities](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) still you can use import like `import throttle from 'lodash/throttle'`. In this way, only one function will be imported

Answer (score 145, accepted):

I would use the [underscore.js](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) or [lodash](https://lodash.com) source code to find a well tested version of this function.

Here is the slightly modified version of the underscore code to remove all references to underscore.js itself:

```
// Returns a function, that, when invoked, will only be triggered at most once
// during a given window of time. Normally, the throttled function will run
// as much as it can, without ever going more than once per `wait` duration;
// but if you'd like to disable the execution on the leading edge, pass
// `{leading: false}`. To disable execution on the trailing edge, ditto.
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
  var context, args, result;
  var timeout = null;
  var previous = 0;
  if (!options) options = {};
  var later = function() {
    previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
    timeout = null;
    result = func.apply(context, args);
    if (!timeout) context = args = null;
  };
  return function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
    var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
      }
      previous = now;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
    }
    return result;
  };
};
```

Please note that this code can be simplified if you don't need all the options that underscore support.

Please find below a very simple and non-configurable version of this function:

```
function throttle (callback, limit) {
    var waiting = false;                      // Initially, we're not waiting
    return function () {                      // We return a throttled function
        if (!waiting) {                       // If we're not waiting
            callback.apply(this, arguments);  // Execute users function
            waiting = true;                   // Prevent future invocations
            setTimeout(function () {          // After a period of time
                waiting = false;              // And allow future invocations
            }, limit);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1: Removed another reference to underscore, thx to @Zettam 's comment

Edit 2: Added suggestion about lodash and possible code simplification, thx to @lolzery @wowzery 's comment

Edit 3: Due to popular requests, I added a very simple, non-configurable version of the function, adapted from @vsync 's comment

Comment: That was only dates I believe? Worked perfectly after the edit! (not all _. referances are removed in your version)

Comment: doesn't look simple to me. This is a [good example](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/m7G64/) of simple

Comment: Indeed, this is not simple. But it's production ready and open-source.

Comment: FWIW, Date.now() doesn't work on ie8 and below. The cross-browser alternative is `new Date().getTime()`. And if you care really a lot about performance what you can do is `(Date.now || function(){ return new Date().getTime(); } )()`.

Comment: One of the reasons this isn't as simple as the one @vsync linked to is because it supports trailing calls. With this one, if you called the resulting function twice, it will result in two calls to the wrapped function: once immediately and once after the delay. In the one vsync linked to, it will result in a single, immediate call, but none after the delay. In many cases, receiving the trailing call is very important in order to get the last viewport size or whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Please do not ever use this. I don't intend to be arrogant. Rather, I just intend to be practical. This answer is waaay more complicated than it needs to be. I posted up a separate answer to this question that does all of this and more in far fewer lines of code.

Comment: You are right in the sense that my main recommendation is to use a library and not re-invent the wheel. The lodash code also provide some options that you may remove to gain in complexity

Comment: @vsync, I've been searching a simple throttle function (like the one you link to) for a while and have found all your comments "this is debounce, not throttle" hilarious. The amount of wrong answers is huge. This is a right answer and your comment is even better. Thank you

Comment: `arguments` is not even defined, and treated as a global. How is this even working?

Comment: @Nico the `arguments` object is always defined inside any function that is not an arrow function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: I've been programming for a while, but every time I come here I discover something new. Thank you @ClémentPrévost

Comment: @vsync the simple example shown by you ignore the last call, which could be a problem, e.g mouse movement for a resize , check https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Comment: This did NOT work for me. No errors, but also does not call the throttled function at all. Using Typescript 3.6.

Comment: Can you please provide your TS adaptation @BluE?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost I plugged in your simple code into this question, but it's not passing.  Do you have any ideas? https://bigfrontend.dev/problem/implement-basic-throttle

Comment: @techguy2000 Good remark. This is because the BigFrontend challenge expects the throttle function to execute the last throttled call once the throttle limit is passed. This simple solution drops the call if we are throtteling and will not call it back later. Both solutions apply to various real world problems. Here is the version you are looking for: https://gist.github.com/prevostc/dcb395fc8ae4cf094e42d262e77746bd

Comment: Thanks so much @ClémentPrévost!

Comment: Does the short version work with functions that return a value? I don't see any return statement

Comment: @diedu It does not, but the underscore/lodash version do. They implement some sort of return value caching to make it work

Comment: why aren't we using `clearTimeout()` otherwise there would be many unused timeout id in stack? instead of  `var waiting = false; ` can we use `let timerId;` in first line and  assign `timerid = setTimeout(...);`

Answer (score 35):

What about this?

```
function throttle(func, timeFrame) {
  var lastTime = 0;
  return function () {
      var now = Date.now();
      if (now - lastTime >= timeFrame) {
          func();
          lastTime = now;
      }
  };
}
```

Simple.

You may be interested in having a look at the [source](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_throttle).

Comment: This is the cleanest minimal implementation on the page.

Comment: For me this only works with `Date.now()` rather than `new Date()`

Comment: I also have a warning in TS when doing `now - lastTime` because `now` is a Date. Replacing by `Date.now()` to get a number seems legit.

Comment: Any downside to this approach compared to using `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Vic the last call to your function is not guaranteed

Comment: How can we ensure a final call to `func` for times when it doesn't get called? E.g. `timeFrame` is 5000, but you call twice within `3000`; the first call is handled but the second is skipped; how can we automatically call `func` for that second call?

Answer (score 14):

**callback**: takes the function that should be called

**limit**: number of times that function should be called within the time limit

**time**: time span to reset the limit count

**functionality and usage**: Suppose you have an API that allows user to call it 10 times in 1 minute

```js
function throttling(callback, limit, time) {
    /// monitor the count
    var calledCount = 0;

    /// refresh the `calledCount` varialbe after the `time` has been passed
    setInterval(function(){ calledCount = 0 }, time);

    /// creating a closure that will be called
    return function(){
        /// checking the limit (if limit is exceeded then do not call the passed function
        if (limit > calledCount) {
            /// increase the count
            calledCount++;
            callback(); /// call the function
        } 
        else console.log('not calling because the limit has exceeded');
    };
}
    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// how to use

/// creating a function to pass in the throttling function 
function cb(){
    console.log("called");
}

/// calling the closure function in every 100 milliseconds
setInterval(throttling(cb, 3, 1000), 100);
```

Comment: @lolzerywowzery It's not like your answer is less complicated than it needs to be

Comment: I would suggest firing the callback like so: `callback(...arguments)` to keep the original arguments. very handy

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and easy.

Comment: @Denny This answer waisted tremendous browser resources. It starts an entire new Intervalling function every single handler it creates. Even after you remove the event listener, the continuous polling drains computer resources, leading to high memory usage, freeze-ups, and page bricks.

Comment: Please do not ever use this answer in production code. This is very opitome of poor programming. Say you have 1000 buttons on your page (which may sound like a lot but think again: buttons hide everywhere: in popups, submenus, panels, etc.) and want to limit each one to fire at most once every 200 seconds Now, since they would likely be all initiated at the same time, every 333 milliseconds (or 3 times a second), there would be a massive lag spike when all of these timers need to check again. This answer completely abuses `setInterval` for purposes it was not intended to do.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the discussion here (and for more recent visitors), if the reason for not using the almost de facto `throttle` from `lodash` is to have a smaller sized package or bundle, then it's possible to include only `throttle` in your bundle instead of the entire `lodash` library. For example in ES6, it would be something like:

```
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';
```

Also, there is a `throttle` only package from `lodash` called [`lodash.throttle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.throttle) which can be used with a simple `import` in ES6 or `require` in ES5.

Comment: Checked the code. it is using 2 files imports, so this means you will need 3 files for a simple throttle function. a bit of an overkill I would say, especially if someone (like myself) needs a throttle function for a ~200 lines of code program.

Comment: Yeah, it internally uses `debounce` and `isObject`, the whole bundle size comes to around [2.1KB minified](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=lodash.throttle@4.1.1). I suppose, doesn't make sense for a small program but I would prefer using it in bigger projects over creating my own throttle function which I would have to test too :)

Comment: prefer `lodash-es` over `lodash` for modern projects

Answer (score 12):

I've just needed a throttle/debounce function for window resize event, and being curious, I also wanted to know what these are and how they work.

I've read multiple blog posts and QAs on SO, but they all seem to overcomplicate this, suggest libraries, or just provide descriptions and not simple plain JS implementations.

I won't provide a description since it's plentiful. So here's my implementation:

```
function throttle(callback, delay) {
    var timeoutHandler = null;
    return function () {
        if (timeoutHandler == null) {
            timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function () {
                callback();
                timeoutHandler = null;
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}

function debounce(callback, delay) {
    var timeoutHandler = null;
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
        timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function () {
            callback();
        }, delay);
    }
}
```

These might need tweaks (e.g., initially the callback isn't called immediately).

See the difference in action (try resizing the window):

```js
function throttle(callback, delay) {
    var timeoutHandler = null;
    return function () {
        if (timeoutHandler == null) {
            timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function () {
                callback();
                timeoutHandler = null;
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}

function debounce(callback, delay) {
    var timeoutHandler = null;
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
        timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function () {
            callback();
        }, delay);
    }
}

var cellDefault  = document.querySelector("#cellDefault div");
var cellThrottle = document.querySelector("#cellThrottle div");
var cellDebounce = document.querySelector("#cellDebounce div");

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = window.innerWidth;
    cellDefault.appendChild(span);
    cellDefault.scrollTop = cellDefault.scrollHeight;
});

window.addEventListener("resize", throttle(function () {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = window.innerWidth;
    cellThrottle.appendChild(span);
    cellThrottle.scrollTop = cellThrottle.scrollHeight;
}, 500));

window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(function () {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = window.innerWidth;
    cellDebounce.appendChild(span);
    cellDebounce.scrollTop = cellDebounce.scrollHeight;
}, 500));
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 10px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 5px;
}
table tr:last-child td div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
table tr:last-child td span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>default</td>
        <td>throttle</td>
        <td>debounce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cellDefault">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td id="cellThrottle">
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td id="cellDebounce">
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/wchbkd7n/)

Comment: Poorly designed and induces a great delay on everything it is attached to which makes the website unresponsive to the user.

Comment: @commonSenseCode What does "does not even work" even mean? I've provided demo code. It clearly works. Try to be more elaborate, please. Whatever is not working, I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with your implementation.

Comment: The clearInterval() call in throttle() doesn't make sense, both because setTimeout() should be paired with clearTimeout() rather than clearInterval(), and because it's meaningless to cancel a timer after it has already fired.

Also, I would expect the first callback to be instant, and subsequent callbacks to be delayed, but I guess delaying the first one too can be good or bad depending on what you want.

Comment: @BillKeese Oh, you're right. There's no need to clear the timeout in the throttle. I suspect it's an artifact from copy/paste/edit of the debounce function. And as for the immediate call, that can be tweaked. I didn't want to complicate the functions with additional features. I'm a fan of the saying *"A picture is worth a thousand words"*, so I wanted to provide simple demos.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I implemented throttle function in ES6 in 9LOC, hope it helps

```
function throttle(func, delay) {
  let timeout = null
  return function(...args) {
    if (!timeout) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        func.call(this, ...args)
        timeout = null
      }, delay)
    }
  }
}
```

Click on this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vipingoyal1000/jgtefqLj/1/) to see how it works.

Comment: Simple, but rather ineffective: it will delay the function even when not appropriate, and it will not keep the pending event fresh, resulting potentially major lag in the user interactions lag. Also, the use of the `...` spread syntax is inappropriate because only 1 argument is ever passed to the event listener: the event object.

Comment: @JackGiffin : Using spread is not inappropriate; nothing limits the throttle function to only being used for an event handler.

Comment: This will fire the `...args` of the initial call, rather the ones of the latest.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen a lot of answers here that are way too complex for "a simple throttle in js".

Almost all of the simpler answers just ignore calls made "in throttle" instead of delaying execution to the next interval.

Here's a simple implementation that also handles calls "in throttle":

```js
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let lastFunc;
  let lastRan = Date.now() - (limit + 1); //enforces a negative value on first run
  return function(...args) {
    const context = this;
    clearTimeout(lastFunc);
    lastFunc = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(context, args);
      lastRan = Date.now();
    }, limit - (Date.now() - lastRan)); //negative values execute immediately
  }
}
```

This is almost the *exact* same implementation for a simple debounce. It just adds a calculation for the timeout delay which requires tracking when the function was last ran. See below:

```js
const debounce = (func, limit) => {
  let lastFunc;
  return function(...args) {
    const context = this;
    clearTimeout(lastFunc);
    lastFunc = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(context, args)
    }, limit); //no calc here, just use limit
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution in ES6. [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/vaskort/pen/XWaxXrV?editors=1011)

```js
const handleOnClick = () => {
  console.log("hello")
}

const throttle = (func, delay) => {
  let timeout = null;

  return function (...args) {
    if (timeout === null) {
      func.apply(this, args);
      
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        timeout = null;
      }, delay)
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", throttle(handleOnClick, 500))
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my own version of [Vikas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975776/6151768) post:

```
throttle: function (callback, limit, time) {
    var calledCount = 0;
    var timeout = null;

    return function () {
        if (limit > calledCount) {
            calledCount++;
            callback(); 
        }
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                calledCount = 0
                timeout = null;
            }, time);
        }
    };
}
```

I find that using `setInterval` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
function throttle(targetFunc, delay){
  let lastFunc;
  let lastTime;

  return function(){
    const _this = this;
    const args = arguments;

    if(!lastTime){
      targetFunc.apply(_this, args);
      lastTime = Date.now();
    } else {
      clearTimeout(lastFunc);
      lastFunc = setTimeout(function(){
        targetFunc.apply(_this, args);
        lastTime = Date.now();
      }, delay - (Date.now() - lastTime));
    }
  }
}
```

Try it :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', throttle(function() {
  console.log('resize!!');
}, 200));
```

Comment: This is the best simple implementation that I've seen but you can actually make is slightly simpler, will add new answer below

Comment: Finally, there is a really right throttle

Answer (score 2):

With leading and trailing invocations:

```js
const throttle = (fn, ms) => {
  let locked = false

  return function () {
    if (!locked) {
      locked = true
      fn.apply(this, arguments)

      setTimeout(() => {
        fn.apply(this, arguments)
        locked = false
      }, ms)
    }
  }
}
```

Test case:

```js
function log({ gender, address }) {
  console.log({
    name: this.name,
    gender,
    address,
  })
}

const jack = {
  name: 'Jack',
  log: throttle(log, 3000),
}

Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => jack.log({ gender: 'Male', address: 'LA' }))
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a npm package with some throttling functions:

> npm install [function-throttler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/function-throttler)

#### throttleAndQueue

Returns a version of your function that can be called at most every W milliseconds, where W is wait. Calls to your func that happen more often than W get queued up to be called every W ms

#### throttledUpdate

Returns a version of your function that can be called at most every W milliseconds, where W is wait. for calls that happen more often than W the last call will be the one called  (last takes precedence)

#### throttle

limits your function to be called at most every W milliseconds, where W is wait. Calls over W get dropped

Answer (score 1):

There is a library suited for this purpose, it's Backburner.js from Ember.

https://github.com/BackburnerJS/

You'd use it so.

```js
var backburner = new Backburner(["task"]); //You need a name for your tasks

function saySomething(words) {
  backburner.throttle("task", console.log.bind(console, words)
  }, 1000);
}


function mainTask() {
  "This will be said with a throttle of 1 second per word!".split(' ').map(saySomething);
}

backburner.run(mainTask)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a throttle function by definition but a debouncer. A callback function takes arguments (args), and still it works wrapped with the debouncer function. Be free to customize delay time according to your app needs. 1 time per 100ms is used for development mode, event "oninput" is just an example for the frequent case of its use:

```
const callback = (...args) => {
  console.count('callback throttled with arguments:', args);
};

const debouncer = (callback, limit) => {
  let timeoutHandler = 'null'

  return (...args) => {
    if (timeoutHandler === 'null') {
      timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {            
        callback(...args)
        timeoutHandler = 'null'
      }, limit)
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('oninput', debouncer(callback, 100));
```

Comment: It also waits 1000 milliseconds before it calls the callback which is not good at all. Users want a responsive page, not a sluggish nightmare.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are wellcome to customize the callback time according to the requirements of your application. Usually it is between 100 and 500 milliseconds. This 1000 milliseconds allows you to check and debug the function.

Comment: @JackGiffin In some scenarios, the leading-edge invocation is not wanted. An example would be an auto-save.

Comment: @pettys If there is no leading-edge invocation, then it is not a throttle function. Rather, it is a debounce function.

Comment: @JackGiffin I don't think that's the correct distinction between throttle and debounce. I believe throttle is, "Invoke no more then x times/sec," whereas debounce is "For sequences of source events where the gap is less than x sec, treat the whole sequence as a single instance." Subtle difference, but well-illustrated here: http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/  It seems to me both throttle and debounce have meaningful and useful no-leading-edge configurations.

Answer (score 1):

In below example, try clicking the button multiple times, but the `myFunc` function would be executed only once in 3 sec.
The function `throttle` is passed with the function to be executed and the delay.It returns a closure, which is stored in `obj.throttleFunc`.
Now since `obj.throttleFunc` stores a closure, the value of `isRunning` is maintained inside it.

```js
function throttle(func, delay) {
  let isRunning;
  return function(...args) {
    let context = this;        // store the context of the object that owns this function
    if(!isRunning) {
      isRunning = true;
      func.apply(context,args) // execute the function with the context of the object that owns it
      setTimeout(function() {
        isRunning = false;
      }, delay);
    }
  }
}

function myFunc(param) {
  console.log(`Called ${this.name} at ${param}th second`);
}

let obj = {
  name: "THROTTLED FUNCTION ",
  throttleFunc: throttle(myFunc, 3000)
}

function handleClick() {
  obj.throttleFunc(new Date().getSeconds());
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <button onclick="handleClick()">Click me</button>
```

---

> If we don't want the context or arguments to be passed, then a simpler
>   version of this would be as following:

```js
function throttle(func, delay) {
  let isRunning;
  return function() {
    if(!isRunning) {
      isRunning = true;
      func()
      setTimeout(function() {
        isRunning = false;
      }, delay);
    }
  }
}

function myFunc() {
  console.log('Called');
}


let throttleFunc = throttle(myFunc, 3000);

function handleClick() {
  throttleFunc();
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also want to suggest a simple solution for when there is only 1 function you know you will call (for example: Search)

here is what i did in my project

```
let throttle;

function search() {
    if (throttle) {
      clearTimeout(throttle);
    }
    throttle = setTimeout(() => {
      sendSearchReq(str)
    }, 500);
  }
```

Search is called on input change event

Comment: This is not exactly a throttle function. Every call to the `search()` function will reset the timeout. So if I were to call the `search()` function above every millisecond, it will only execute the `sendSearchReq` once and then never again, instead of every 500 ms. This function is more of a delay, than a throttle.

Comment: This is debounce not throttle

Answer (score 1):

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-throttle-function-4ucyh?file=/src/throttle.js)

```js
const { now } = Date;

export default function throttle(func, frameDuration) {
  let timeout = null;
  let latest;
  const epoch = now();

  function getDurationToNextFrame() {
    const elapsed = now() - epoch;
    const durationSinceLastFrame = elapsed % frameDuration;
    return frameDuration - durationSinceLastFrame;
  }

  function throttled(...args) {
    latest = () => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    };
    if (!timeout) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        latest();
        timeout = null;
      }, getDurationToNextFrame());
    }
  }

  return throttled;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some great solutions here already, but I was looking for a modern version with trailing (and optionally leading) executions, with the last passed arguments provided to each function call:

```js
const throttle = (fn, wait=500, leading=true) => {
  let prev, timeout, lastargs;
  return (...args) => {
    lastargs = args;
    if (timeout) return;
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null;
      prev = Date.now();
      // let's do this ... we'll release the stored args as we pass them through
      fn.apply(this, lastargs.splice(0, lastargs.length));
      // some fancy timing logic to allow leading / sub-offset waiting periods
    }, leading ? prev && Math.max(0, wait - Date.now() + prev) || 0 : wait);
  };
}
```

Usage:

```js
x = throttle((...args) => console.log(...args));
let n = 0;
x(++n, 'boom');
x(++n, 'boom');
x(++n, 'boom');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple throttle function -

Note- Keep on clicking on the button , You'll see console log at first on click and then only after every 5 seconds until you're keep clicking.

HTML -

```
<button id='myid'>Click me</button>
```

Javascript -

```
const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
  let lastTime = 0;
  return (...args) => {
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      if((currentTime - lastTime) < delay) {
        return;
      };
      lastTime = currentTime;
      return fn(...args);
  }
};

document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', throttle((e) => {
  console.log('I am clicked');
}, 5000));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also implement using a flag-

```js
var expensive = function(){
    console.log("expensive functionnns");
}

window.addEventListener("resize", throttle(expensive, 500))

function throttle(expensiveFun, limit){
    let flag = true;
    return function(){
        let context = this;
        let args = arguments;
        if(flag){
            expensiveFun.apply(context, args);
            flag = false;
            setTimeout(function(){
                flag = true;
            }, limit);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit modernized and simplified version of [@clément-prévost answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27078401/1065780)

```js
function throttle(func, wait, options = {}) {
  let timeout = null;
  let previous = 0;

  const later = (...args) => {
    previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
    func(...args);
  };

  return (...args) => {
    const now = Date.now();

    if (!previous && options.leading === false) {
      previous = now;
    }

    const remaining = wait - (now - previous);

    if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
      }
      previous = now;
      func(...args);
    } else if (options.trailing !== false) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => later(...args), remaining);
    }
  };
}

function myFunc(a) {
  console.log(`Log: ${a} ${this.val}`);
}

const myFuncThrottled = throttle(myFunc.bind({val: 42}), 1234, {leading: true, trailing: true})

myFuncThrottled(1)
myFuncThrottled(2)
myFuncThrottled(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function throttle(CB,ms=300,Id='Identifier for the callback(CB)'){
  Id = Id || ""+CB
  var N = throttle.N = throttle.N || {};  // Static variable N to store all callbacks ids and their status 
  if( N[Id] ) return;             // already in the queue to run 
  N[Id] = 1;                      // add it the queue 
  setTimeout(()=>{
    N[Id] = 0;                    // remove it from the queue
    CB();                         // finally call the function 
  }, ms);
}



for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
   throttle(e=>console.log("Hi1"),1e3,'F1');
}

// will only  output : Hi1
// this function guarantee the callback to run at least once
```

Answer (score 0):

if there will be more than one function defining them one by one would not be maintainable so i would suggest use a helper class to keep values for each

```js
class slowDown {
    constructor(cb,timeGap){
        this.last = 0
        this.run = function(){
            let current = Date.now(),
                shouldRun = (current - this.last) >= timeGap
            if(shouldRun){
                cb(current - this.last)
                this.last = current
            }            
        }
    }
}

// example use
const press = new slowDown(timeElapsed => {
    // define function here which you wanted to slow down
    console.log("pressed after " + timeElapsed + " ms")
},750)

window.addEventListener("keydown",()=>{
    press.run()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the simplest throttle I could think of, in 13 LOC. It creates a timeout each time the function is called and cancels the old one. The original function is called with the proper context and arguments, as expected.

```js
function throttle(fn, delay) {
  var timeout = null;

  return function throttledFn() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    var ctx = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    timeout = window.setTimeout(function callThrottledFn() {
      fn.apply(ctx, args);
    }, delay);
  }
}

// try it out!
window.addEventListener('resize', throttle(function() {
  console.log('resize!!');
}, 200));
```

Comment: This is a debounce, not a throttle. If i call this 100 in 1000ms, it will fire 1 time after 1200ms. A throttled function should fire 5 times