# how to enforce a minimum delay time among function executions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, delay

I am writing a node function whose executions should be not too close in time (say 5 seconds).

I need to enforce the minimum delay *inside* the function, and not on the calling side, since its user should know nothing about the delay.
This is the reason why I can't use logic similar to [delay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay) or [delayed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delayed) node modules...

Note that I cannot simply `setTimeout()` wrap the function code either, since I want to enforce a minimum delay among executions (i.e.: the first execution should start immediately).

Comment: You can simply use setTimeout...

Comment: What you're looking for is a throttle function. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js for a function into which you can pass your function, along with a throttle time.

Comment: @Jonas w: no, I can't: the function could be called 100 times at the same moment: after 5 seconds it should start 100 executions together...

Comment: @Arnav Aggarwal: I think I'll go with underscore throttle logic, thanks...

Comment: @MarcoS you could. Put all calls into an array, then iterate over them with setTimeout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck)? Maybe you want to wrap your function?

Comment: Thanks. If I fail for some reason to use Arnav Aggarwal suggested throttle, I'll try bottleneck...

Comment: Throttle solution didn't work for me. bottleneck limiter was a breeze.