# Elasticsearch Fluid research

Tags: elasticsearch, vue.js, elastic-cloud

I'm currently using Elasticsearch with Vue.js and I added a search bar so when I search words it showed me what I want but when I search "usa" it go on and off for earch letter it's not fluid.

Do you have any ideas to what I have to use to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like the [Throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) function in Lodash or any other similar library. If you don't want to use another library you could see this other question here on S.O. : [Simple throttle in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js)

This will prevent to call the search for every time your type, waiting a few milliseconds before firing the call, avoiding consecutives requests avoiding that flickering behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious and complete library simplifying building great search UIs for ElasticSearch using Vue.js
[vue-innersearch](https://github.com/InnerSearch/vue-innersearch)