# Cancelling multiple API calls in Vue.js with Axios

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm working on a dashboard with multiple 'modules' that each have their own API calls. Most of the endpoints are snappy but there is a couple that can take a few seconds.

I have a filtering option for date range and every time that changes I re run the API calls for the data.

The issue is that I don't want the user to be able to stack up the API calls if they keep changing their date range quickly before the others have loaded.

Im using a single file vue component, and have a method for each API call and then a single method that groups and calls these.

```
watch: {
    dateFilter: function() {
        this.initStatModules();
    }
},
methods: {
    getCustomers: function() {
        var $this = this;
        return axios.get(`/api/v1/reports/${$this.team.id}/stats-dashboard/customers?date=${$this.dateFilter}`).then(function(response) {
            $this.customers = response.data;
        });
    },
    getBookings: function() {
        var $this = this;
        return axios.get(`/api/v1/reports/${$this.team.id}/stats-dashboard/bookings`).then(function(response) {
            $this.bookings = response.data;
        });
    },
    getTotalRevenue: function() {
        var $this = this;
        return axios.get(`/api/v1/reports/${$this.team.id}/services-revenue?date=${$this.dateFilter}`).then(function(response) {
            $this.totalRevenue = response.data.data.totalRevenue;
        });

    },
    initStatModules: function() {
        this.getCustomers();
        this.getBookings();
        this.getTotalRevenue();
    }
}
```

What I wish to be able to do is cancel all the pending API requests in the watch or initStatModules method.

Looking at the axios docs: https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation it is supported, but I cannot get my head around how to implement it as I wish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to avoid the calls instead of cancelling, Axios says that it is implemented on a draft and in this situation it looks like avoiding calls would be enough.

What I mean by that:

Don't let the user filter if is there a filter call happening. You need to use async/await or Promises to have a better control for that also.

for example, one data property like:

```
isFiltering: false
```

Using promises like you did (omitting your code here, but it's the same idea for the others methods) :

```
methods: {
  getCustomers: async function () {
      var $this = this;
      this.isFiltering = true;
      return axios.get(`/api/v1/reports/${$this.team.id}/stats-dashboard/customers?date=${$this.dateFilter}`).then(function(response) {
          $this.customers = response.data;
          $this.isFiltering = false;
      });
  }
}
```

In your HTML use the `isFiltering` to disable(adding CSS or anyway you wish) the input. That would prevent the user to change the filtering and will look like the filtering is executing. Remember to add the `.catch` part to set the `isFiltering` to false if something went wrong. Using `.finally` if is available would be even better

`if isFiltering then disable`

Another way would be to use [Throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) from Lodash or any other solution, or this implementation suggested here on S.O.: [Simple throttle in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js)

That throttle option is just better to avoid consecutive calls, like when the user is typing in an input.

Comment: Thanks, this was my back up option but you helped explain it. All filtering is done via drop downs so I will disable them for now. Hopefully the API calls will be quick enough not to need it too much but I know Chrome has stalled a couple of times.

Comment: Yeah, I know how it is. I do agree that if the user mistakenly chose a wrong input(dropdown select) it would be annoying to wait if took that long. But imo preventing it's more testable and guaranteed behavior. Because I wouldn't like to depend that much on the cancel behavior. But in the end it's your call. Good luck =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <input type="date" :disabled="isDisabled" v-model="dateFilter">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      dateFilter: null,
      modulesLoaded: 0,
      isDisabled: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    dateFilter () {
      this.initStatModules()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getCustomers () {
      axios.get(`/api/v1/reports/${$this.team.id}/stats-dashboard/customers?date=${$this.dateFilter}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.customers = response.data
          this.onModuleLoaded()
        })
    },
    getBookings () {
      axios.get(`/api/v1/reports/${$this.team.id}/stats-dashboard/bookings`)
        .then(response => {
          this.bookings = response.data
          this.onModuleLoaded()
        })
    },
    getTotalRevenue () {
      axios.get(`/api/v1/reports/${$this.team.id}/services-revenue?date=${$this.dateFilter}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.totalRevenue = response.data.data.totalRevenue
          this.onModuleLoaded()
        })
    },
    initStatModules () {
      this.isDisabled = true
      this.modulesLoaded = 0
      this.getCustomers()
      this.getBookings()
      this.getTotalRevenue()
    },
    onModuleLoaded () {
      this.modulesLoaded++
      if (this.modulesLoaded === 3) {
        this.isDisabled = false
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

try this.

Comment: You should avoid code-only answers. Please provide some explanation