# Two signature pads in one form

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to implement two signature pads in ONE form. One signature is for the applicant and the other one is for the evaluator.
The first pad works but the second pad is unresponsive. I am using JavaScript for the signature pads but it only works for the first pad. The signature will be saved to the database when the submit button is clicked. That is why `id="save-signature-btn"` is together with the code for the 'Submit' button.

**form.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'page3/submit']) !!}

<h4 style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold">Approved By:</h4>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Approved By:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Name</th>
        <th colspan="1">Signature</th>
        <th colspan="1">Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan=4>
        <td colspan="1">
            <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::text('Officer_Name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'John Smith'])}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <div class="form-group">

            <canvas id="signature-canvas" style="width:375px;height:150px;max-width:100%;border:8px #CCC solid;background-color: white;"></canvas>

            <div id="signature-message"></div>

            <div id="signature-buttons">
                <input type="button" id="clear-signature-btn" value="Clear"> 
            </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="officer_signature" id="signature-data" value="">

            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::date('Approval_Date', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<h4 style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold">Applicant Signature:</h4>

            <div class="form-group">

            <canvas id="signature-canvas2" style="width:375px;height:150px;max-width:100%;border:8px #CCC solid;background-color: white;"></canvas>

            <div id="signature-message2"></div>

            <div id="signature-buttons2">
                <input type="button" id="clear-signature-btn2" value="Clear"> 
            </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="applicant_signature" id="signature-data2" value="">

            </div>


<br>

            <div class="signature_pad_save">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-signature-btn">Submit</button>
            </div>


<script src="js/signature_pad.js"></script>
<script src="js/signature_data.js"></script>


</body>
</html>

@endsection('content')
```

**signature data.js**

```
var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear-signature-btn'),
    saveButton = document.getElementById('save-signature-btn'),
    canvas = document.getElementById('signature-canvas'),
    signaturePad;

function resizeCanvas() {
    var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

clearButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    signaturePad.clear();
});

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
        alert('Signature pad is blank. Please draw your signature.');
    } else {
        var sdata = signaturePad.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById('signature-data').value = sdata;
        document.getElementById('signature-form').submit();
    }
});
```

**signature pad.js**

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.SignaturePad = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

function Point(x, y, time) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.time = time || new Date().getTime();
}

Point.prototype.velocityFrom = function (start) {
  return this.time !== start.time ? this.distanceTo(start) / (this.time - start.time) : 1;
};

Point.prototype.distanceTo = function (start) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - start.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y - start.y, 2));
};

Point.prototype.equals = function (other) {
  return this.x === other.x && this.y === other.y && this.time === other.time;
};

function Bezier(startPoint, control1, control2, endPoint) {
  this.startPoint = startPoint;
  this.control1 = control1;
  this.control2 = control2;
  this.endPoint = endPoint;
}

// Returns approximated length.
Bezier.prototype.length = function () {
  var steps = 10;
  var length = 0;
  var px = void 0;
  var py = void 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= steps; i += 1) {
    var t = i / steps;
    var cx = this._point(t, this.startPoint.x, this.control1.x, this.control2.x, this.endPoint.x);
    var cy = this._point(t, this.startPoint.y, this.control1.y, this.control2.y, this.endPoint.y);
    if (i > 0) {
      var xdiff = cx - px;
      var ydiff = cy - py;
      length += Math.sqrt(xdiff * xdiff + ydiff * ydiff);
    }
    px = cx;
    py = cy;
  }

  return length;
};

/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces, space-in-parens */
Bezier.prototype._point = function (t, start, c1, c2, end) {
  return start * (1.0 - t) * (1.0 - t) * (1.0 - t) + 3.0 * c1 * (1.0 - t) * (1.0 - t) * t + 3.0 * c2 * (1.0 - t) * t * t + end * t * t * t;
};

/* eslint-disable */

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/27078401/815507
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
  var context, args, result;
  var timeout = null;
  var previous = 0;
  if (!options) options = {};
  var later = function later() {
    previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
    timeout = null;
    result = func.apply(context, args);
    if (!timeout) context = args = null;
  };
  return function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
    var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
      }
      previous = now;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
    }
    return result;
  };
}

function SignaturePad(canvas, options) {
  var self = this;
  var opts = options || {};

  this.velocityFilterWeight = opts.velocityFilterWeight || 0.7;
  this.minWidth = opts.minWidth || 0.5;
  this.maxWidth = opts.maxWidth || 2.5;
  this.throttle = 'throttle' in opts ? opts.throttle : 16; // in miliseconds
  this.minDistance = 'minDistance' in opts ? opts.minDistance : 5;

  if (this.throttle) {
    this._strokeMoveUpdate = throttle(SignaturePad.prototype._strokeUpdate, this.throttle);
  } else {
    this._strokeMoveUpdate = SignaturePad.prototype._strokeUpdate;
  }

  this.dotSize = opts.dotSize || function () {
    return (this.minWidth + this.maxWidth) / 2;
  };
  this.penColor = opts.penColor || 'black';
  this.backgroundColor = opts.backgroundColor || 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  this.onBegin = opts.onBegin;
  this.onEnd = opts.onEnd;

  this._canvas = canvas;
  this._ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.clear();

  // We need add these inline so they are available to unbind while still having
  // access to 'self' we could use _.bind but it's not worth adding a dependency.
  this._handleMouseDown = function (event) {
    if (event.which === 1) {
      self._mouseButtonDown = true;
      self._strokeBegin(event);
    }
  };

  this._handleMouseMove = function (event) {
    if (self._mouseButtonDown) {
      self._strokeMoveUpdate(event);
    }
  };

  this._handleMouseUp = function (event) {
    if (event.which === 1 && self._mouseButtonDown) {
      self._mouseButtonDown = false;
      self._strokeEnd(event);
    }
  };

  this._handleTouchStart = function (event) {
    if (event.targetTouches.length === 1) {
      var touch = event.changedTouches[0];
      self._strokeBegin(touch);
    }
  };

  this._handleTouchMove = function (event) {
    // Prevent scrolling.
    event.preventDefault();

    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    self._strokeMoveUpdate(touch);
  };

  this._handleTouchEnd = function (event) {
    var wasCanvasTouched = event.target === self._canvas;
    if (wasCanvasTouched) {
      event.preventDefault();
      self._strokeEnd(event);
    }
  };

  // Enable mouse and touch event handlers
  this.on();
}

// Public methods
SignaturePad.prototype.clear = function () {
  var ctx = this._ctx;
  var canvas = this._canvas;

  ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  this._data = [];
  this._reset();
  this._isEmpty = true;
};

SignaturePad.prototype.fromDataURL = function (dataUrl) {
  var _this = this;

  var options = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : {};

  var image = new Image();
  var ratio = options.ratio || window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  var width = options.width || this._canvas.width / ratio;
  var height = options.height || this._canvas.height / ratio;

  this._reset();
  image.src = dataUrl;
  image.onload = function () {
    _this._ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  };
  this._isEmpty = false;
};

SignaturePad.prototype.toDataURL = function (type) {
  var _canvas;

  switch (type) {
    case 'image/svg+xml':
      return this._toSVG();
    default:
      for (var _len = arguments.length, options = Array(_len > 1 ? _len - 1 : 0), _key = 1; _key < _len; _key++) {
        options[_key - 1] = arguments[_key];
      }

      return (_canvas = this._canvas).toDataURL.apply(_canvas, [type].concat(options));
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype.on = function () {
  this._handleMouseEvents();
  this._handleTouchEvents();
};

SignaturePad.prototype.off = function () {
  this._canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', this._handleMouseDown);
  this._canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', this._handleMouseMove);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this._handleMouseUp);

  this._canvas.removeEventListener('touchstart', this._handleTouchStart);
  this._canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', this._handleTouchMove);
  this._canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', this._handleTouchEnd);
};

SignaturePad.prototype.isEmpty = function () {
  return this._isEmpty;
};

// Private methods
SignaturePad.prototype._strokeBegin = function (event) {
  this._data.push([]);
  this._reset();
  this._strokeUpdate(event);

  if (typeof this.onBegin === 'function') {
    this.onBegin(event);
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype._strokeUpdate = function (event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;

  var point = this._createPoint(x, y);
  var lastPointGroup = this._data[this._data.length - 1];
  var lastPoint = lastPointGroup && lastPointGroup[lastPointGroup.length - 1];
  var isLastPointTooClose = lastPoint && point.distanceTo(lastPoint) < this.minDistance;

  // Skip this point if it's too close to the previous one
  if (!(lastPoint && isLastPointTooClose)) {
    var _addPoint = this._addPoint(point),
        curve = _addPoint.curve,
        widths = _addPoint.widths;

    if (curve && widths) {
      this._drawCurve(curve, widths.start, widths.end);
    }

    this._data[this._data.length - 1].push({
      x: point.x,
      y: point.y,
      time: point.time,
      color: this.penColor
    });
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype._strokeEnd = function (event) {
  var canDrawCurve = this.points.length > 2;
  var point = this.points[0]; // Point instance

  if (!canDrawCurve && point) {
    this._drawDot(point);
  }

  if (point) {
    var lastPointGroup = this._data[this._data.length - 1];
    var lastPoint = lastPointGroup[lastPointGroup.length - 1]; // plain object

    // When drawing a dot, there's only one point in a group, so without this check
    // such group would end up with exactly the same 2 points.
    if (!point.equals(lastPoint)) {
      lastPointGroup.push({
        x: point.x,
        y: point.y,
        time: point.time,
        color: this.penColor
      });
    }
  }

  if (typeof this.onEnd === 'function') {
    this.onEnd(event);
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype._handleMouseEvents = function () {
  this._mouseButtonDown = false;

  this._canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this._handleMouseDown);
  this._canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this._handleMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', this._handleMouseUp);
};

SignaturePad.prototype._handleTouchEvents = function () {
  // Pass touch events to canvas element on mobile IE11 and Edge.
  this._canvas.style.msTouchAction = 'none';
  this._canvas.style.touchAction = 'none';

  this._canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', this._handleTouchStart);
  this._canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', this._handleTouchMove);
  this._canvas.addEventListener('touchend', this._handleTouchEnd);
};

SignaturePad.prototype._reset = function () {
  this.points = [];
  this._lastVelocity = 0;
  this._lastWidth = (this.minWidth + this.maxWidth) / 2;
  this._ctx.fillStyle = this.penColor;
};

SignaturePad.prototype._createPoint = function (x, y, time) {
  var rect = this._canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  return new Point(x - rect.left, y - rect.top, time || new Date().getTime());
};

SignaturePad.prototype._addPoint = function (point) {
  var points = this.points;
  var tmp = void 0;

  points.push(point);

  if (points.length > 2) {
    // To reduce the initial lag make it work with 3 points
    // by copying the first point to the beginning.
    if (points.length === 3) points.unshift(points[0]);

    tmp = this._calculateCurveControlPoints(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
    var c2 = tmp.c2;
    tmp = this._calculateCurveControlPoints(points[1], points[2], points[3]);
    var c3 = tmp.c1;
    var curve = new Bezier(points[1], c2, c3, points[2]);
    var widths = this._calculateCurveWidths(curve);

    // Remove the first element from the list,
    // so that we always have no more than 4 points in points array.
    points.shift();

    return { curve: curve, widths: widths };
  }

  return {};
};

SignaturePad.prototype._calculateCurveControlPoints = function (s1, s2, s3) {
  var dx1 = s1.x - s2.x;
  var dy1 = s1.y - s2.y;
  var dx2 = s2.x - s3.x;
  var dy2 = s2.y - s3.y;

  var m1 = { x: (s1.x + s2.x) / 2.0, y: (s1.y + s2.y) / 2.0 };
  var m2 = { x: (s2.x + s3.x) / 2.0, y: (s2.y + s3.y) / 2.0 };

  var l1 = Math.sqrt(dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1);
  var l2 = Math.sqrt(dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2);

  var dxm = m1.x - m2.x;
  var dym = m1.y - m2.y;

  var k = l2 / (l1 + l2);
  var cm = { x: m2.x + dxm * k, y: m2.y + dym * k };

  var tx = s2.x - cm.x;
  var ty = s2.y - cm.y;

  return {
    c1: new Point(m1.x + tx, m1.y + ty),
    c2: new Point(m2.x + tx, m2.y + ty)
  };
};

SignaturePad.prototype._calculateCurveWidths = function (curve) {
  var startPoint = curve.startPoint;
  var endPoint = curve.endPoint;
  var widths = { start: null, end: null };

  var velocity = this.velocityFilterWeight * endPoint.velocityFrom(startPoint) + (1 - this.velocityFilterWeight) * this._lastVelocity;

  var newWidth = this._strokeWidth(velocity);

  widths.start = this._lastWidth;
  widths.end = newWidth;

  this._lastVelocity = velocity;
  this._lastWidth = newWidth;

  return widths;
};

SignaturePad.prototype._strokeWidth = function (velocity) {
  return Math.max(this.maxWidth / (velocity + 1), this.minWidth);
};

SignaturePad.prototype._drawPoint = function (x, y, size) {
  var ctx = this._ctx;

  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  this._isEmpty = false;
};

SignaturePad.prototype._drawCurve = function (curve, startWidth, endWidth) {
  var ctx = this._ctx;
  var widthDelta = endWidth - startWidth;
  var drawSteps = Math.floor(curve.length());

  ctx.beginPath();

  for (var i = 0; i < drawSteps; i += 1) {
    // Calculate the Bezier (x, y) coordinate for this step.
    var t = i / drawSteps;
    var tt = t * t;
    var ttt = tt * t;
    var u = 1 - t;
    var uu = u * u;
    var uuu = uu * u;

    var x = uuu * curve.startPoint.x;
    x += 3 * uu * t * curve.control1.x;
    x += 3 * u * tt * curve.control2.x;
    x += ttt * curve.endPoint.x;

    var y = uuu * curve.startPoint.y;
    y += 3 * uu * t * curve.control1.y;
    y += 3 * u * tt * curve.control2.y;
    y += ttt * curve.endPoint.y;

    var width = startWidth + ttt * widthDelta;
    this._drawPoint(x, y, width);
  }

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
};

SignaturePad.prototype._drawDot = function (point) {
  var ctx = this._ctx;
  var width = typeof this.dotSize === 'function' ? this.dotSize() : this.dotSize;

  ctx.beginPath();
  this._drawPoint(point.x, point.y, width);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
};

SignaturePad.prototype._fromData = function (pointGroups, drawCurve, drawDot) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pointGroups.length; i += 1) {
    var group = pointGroups[i];

    if (group.length > 1) {
      for (var j = 0; j < group.length; j += 1) {
        var rawPoint = group[j];
        var point = new Point(rawPoint.x, rawPoint.y, rawPoint.time);
        var color = rawPoint.color;

        if (j === 0) {
          // First point in a group. Nothing to draw yet.

          // All points in the group have the same color, so it's enough to set
          // penColor just at the beginning.
          this.penColor = color;
          this._reset();

          this._addPoint(point);
        } else if (j !== group.length - 1) {
          // Middle point in a group.
          var _addPoint2 = this._addPoint(point),
              curve = _addPoint2.curve,
              widths = _addPoint2.widths;

          if (curve && widths) {
            drawCurve(curve, widths, color);
          }
        } else {
          // Last point in a group. Do nothing.
        }
      }
    } else {
      this._reset();
      var _rawPoint = group[0];
      drawDot(_rawPoint);
    }
  }
};

SignaturePad.prototype._toSVG = function () {
  var _this2 = this;

  var pointGroups = this._data;
  var canvas = this._canvas;
  var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
  var minX = 0;
  var minY = 0;
  var maxX = canvas.width / ratio;
  var maxY = canvas.height / ratio;
  var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

  svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', canvas.width);
  svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', canvas.height);

  this._fromData(pointGroups, function (curve, widths, color) {
    var path = document.createElement('path');

    // Need to check curve for NaN values, these pop up when drawing
    // lines on the canvas that are not continuous. E.g. Sharp corners
    // or stopping mid-stroke and than continuing without lifting mouse.
    if (!isNaN(curve.control1.x) && !isNaN(curve.control1.y) && !isNaN(curve.control2.x) && !isNaN(curve.control2.y)) {
      var attr = 'M ' + curve.startPoint.x.toFixed(3) + ',' + curve.startPoint.y.toFixed(3) + ' ' + ('C ' + curve.control1.x.toFixed(3) + ',' + curve.control1.y.toFixed(3) + ' ') + (curve.control2.x.toFixed(3) + ',' + curve.control2.y.toFixed(3) + ' ') + (curve.endPoint.x.toFixed(3) + ',' + curve.endPoint.y.toFixed(3));

      path.setAttribute('d', attr);
      path.setAttribute('stroke-width', (widths.end * 2.25).toFixed(3));
      path.setAttribute('stroke', color);
      path.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
      path.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');

      svg.appendChild(path);
    }
  }, function (rawPoint) {
    var circle = document.createElement('circle');
    var dotSize = typeof _this2.dotSize === 'function' ? _this2.dotSize() : _this2.dotSize;
    circle.setAttribute('r', dotSize);
    circle.setAttribute('cx', rawPoint.x);
    circle.setAttribute('cy', rawPoint.y);
    circle.setAttribute('fill', rawPoint.color);

    svg.appendChild(circle);
  });

  var prefix = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
  var header = '<svg' + ' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"' + ' xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"' + (' viewBox="' + minX + ' ' + minY + ' ' + maxX + ' ' + maxY + '"') + (' width="' + maxX + '"') + (' height="' + maxY + '"') + '>';
  var body = svg.innerHTML;

  // IE hack for missing innerHTML property on SVGElement
  if (body === undefined) {
    var dummy = document.createElement('dummy');
    var nodes = svg.childNodes;
    dummy.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
      dummy.appendChild(nodes[i].cloneNode(true));
    }

    body = dummy.innerHTML;
  }

  var footer = '</svg>';
  var data = header + body + footer;

  return prefix + btoa(data);
};

SignaturePad.prototype.fromData = function (pointGroups) {
  var _this3 = this;

  this.clear();

  this._fromData(pointGroups, function (curve, widths) {
    return _this3._drawCurve(curve, widths.start, widths.end);
  }, function (rawPoint) {
    return _this3._drawDot(rawPoint);
  });

  this._data = pointGroups;
};

SignaturePad.prototype.toData = function () {
  return this._data;
};

return SignaturePad;

})));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code you are working only with

```
canvas = document.getElementById('signature-canvas')
```

So that is the problem.

You should add a class on both signature canvases in html code for example `signature` like this:

```
<canvas id="signature-canvas" class="signature" style="width:375px;height:150px;max-width:100%;border:8px #CCC solid;background-color: white;"></canvas>

<canvas id="signature-canvas2" class="signature" style="width:375px;height:150px;max-width:100%;border:8px #CCC solid;background-color: white;"></canvas>
```

And then in javascript add one more pair of commands for second signature pad for control buttons (submit and reset) for second canvas.

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work

this is the code 
--  var clearButton = document.getElementById('clear-signature-btn'),
 saveButton = document.getElementById('save-signature-btn'),
 canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('signature'),
 signaturePad;

<canvas class="signature" style="width:375px;height:150px;max-width:100%;border:8px #CCC solid;background-color: white;"></canvas>

Comment: You need then the id selector  too. Try to figure it out. The point is that with class selector you 'turn on' the canvases and with Id selector you communicate with each of them separately. I hope this makes sense to you.