# Is there a way to make a "cooldown" to your function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im currently making a diashow or a slideshow for an website. And everything is set up except one thing. The user is able to spam the slideshow thus resulting in skipped animation. I want to add a cooldown to skipping the slides manually. But i couldnt figure out any solution. Help is appreciated!

Heres a fiddle of the diashow: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/rc5xnqud/)

```js
var images = [
  "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789187560407045/picture1.png)",
  "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789189162762240/picture2.png)",
  "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789190500614147/picture3.png)",
  "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789199837265929/picture4.png)"
];
var num = 0;
var interval = setInterval(next, 5000);

function next() {
  var diashow = document.getElementById("diashow");
  num++;
  if (num >= images.length) {
    num = 0;
  }
  diashow.style.backgroundImage = images[num];
}

function prev() {
  var diashow = document.getElementById("diashow");
  num--;
  if (num < 0) {
    num = images.length - 1;
  }
  diashow.style.backgroundImage = images[num];
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function set() {
  interval = setInterval(next, 5000);
}
```

```css
#diashow {
  user-select: none;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  width: 600px;
  height: 224px;
  background-size: 600px 224px;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789187560407045/picture1.png);
}

#diashow div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 224px;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#divleft:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 50px 0px 0px 0px white;
}

#divright:hover {
  box-shadow: inset -50px 0px 0px 0px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="diashow" onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="set()">
  <div id="divleft" onclick="prev()"></div>
  <div id="divright" onclick="next()"></div>
</div>
```

*edit i checked the fiddle and apparently even the changing of the slides doesnt work *sigh*

Comment: Please post the code of a MCVE (mimimal, complete, viable example) within the text of your question -- *not* on an external site susceptible to link rot.

Comment: Agreed with above. Posting code on SO is easy, and it will help you receive the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt work. Click `Javascript + No-Library (Pure JS)` => `Load type` => `No wrap - bottom of <body>` and save to fix this. BTW I don't know what you are trying to achive. What animation are you talking about?

Comment: Im trying to add a cooldown for users to not be able to spam the clicking on the divs that change the pictures manually. If you spam really fast on the div the smooth animation gets cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put a `delay` and a 'lastClick' variable in your code. I have tested it, it is working:

```
var delay = 800;
var lastClick = 0;
var images = [
    "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789187560407045/picture1.png)",
    "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789189162762240/picture2.png)",
    "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789190500614147/picture3.png)",
    "url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/461567193927385091/534789199837265929/picture4.png)"];
var num = 0;
var interval = setInterval(next, 5000);
function next(){
    console.log(lastClick);
    if (lastClick >= (Date.now() - delay))
        return;
    lastClick = Date.now();
    var diashow = document.getElementById("diashow");
    num++;
    if(num >= images.length){num = 0;}diashow.style.backgroundImage = images[num];}
function prev(){
    if (lastClick >= (Date.now() - delay))
        return;
    lastClick = Date.now();
    var diashow = document.getElementById("diashow");
    num--;
    if(num < 0) {num = images.length-1;}diashow.style.backgroundImage = images[num];}
function stop(){clearInterval(interval);}
function set(){interval = setInterval(next, 5000);}
```

Feel free to edit the `delay` variable.

PS: The `var` keyword is outdated, please check out `let` and `const`.

Comment: looks promising. gonna try it out and update you guys

Comment: That is nice. No problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to work, I am a learner to javascript as well.
Suppose there is a button click function called `click1()` and there is a function called `loadclick1()` so in short this would look like

```
function loadclick1() {
    if (//button-clicked) {
        function click1() {
            //Animation code here;
            setTimeout(loadclick1(), 3000) //This will set a timeout until the function is ready
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same idea, but for a cooldown for the function triggered by a button (to avoid spamming the server programmatically or not)

my problem was to **not let the cooldown variables accessible via javascripting**

i worked it around like that :

```js
const buttonFunction = (function setup () { 
// const prevents from reassigning
  const coolDown = 5000 // 5s cooldown
  let lastClick = Date.now() - coolDown // to start fresh

  function startCoolDown () {
    lastClick = Date.now() // maybe useless function
  }
  function checkCoolDown () {
    const notOver = Date.now() - lastClick < coolDown
    if (notOver) alert('stop spamming the server !')
    // using an alert it will block javascript loops
    return !notOver
  }

  return function (arguments) {
    if (checkCoolDown()) {
      startCoolDown()

      // do your stuff with arguments here
    }
  }
})() // all variables are safely nested !
```

and the HTML button :

```html
<button onclick="buttonFunction('argument')">
  button
</button>
```

So far it seems to be bullet-proof,
Does anybody see a flaw ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash library and it's `throttle()` function, much quicker and cleaner.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

What you're thinking of is called "throttling"

This SO question has a solution for you:
[Simple throttle in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js)

Shameless copy paste of the above:

```
// Returns a function, that, when invoked, will only be triggered at most once
// during a given window of time. Normally, the throttled function will run
// as much as it can, without ever going more than once per `wait` duration;
// but if you'd like to disable the execution on the leading edge, pass
// `{leading: false}`. To disable execution on the trailing edge, ditto.
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
  var context, args, result;
  var timeout = null;
  var previous = 0;
  if (!options) options = {};
  var later = function() {
    previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
    timeout = null;
    result = func.apply(context, args);
    if (!timeout) context = args = null;
  };
  return function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
    var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
      }
      previous = now;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
    }
    return result;
  };
};
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21938755)

Comment: Will remember that for the future. Thanks.