# How to calculate transparent area of canvas in percentage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, ionic-framework, html5-canvas

I am making a drawing app in Ionic 4, In this app, I added the number 1 image in canvas using drawImage and the rest of the image background is transparent. If the user(kids) draw outside of the number 1 image, the percentage will decrease. For this, I search but didn't find anything but I found click to find is pixel is transparent or not.

```
isTransparent(x, y) { // x, y coordinate of pixel
let alpha = this.ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3]; // 3rd byte is alpha

if (alpha === 0) {
  this.accuracy = 0;
  console.log("Transparent image clicked!");
} else {
  this.accuracy = 100;
  console.log("image clicked!");
}
}
```

The [code sample](https://github.com/gokujy/ioniccanvas.github.io) I added on GitHub and here is [live Demo](https://ioncanvas.sitesforhosting.co.in/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; however, according to https://github.com/gokujy/ioniccanvas.github.io/blob/aa9c9ea44f745d5843cc1f1a9f88bd7d4709d354/src/app/pages/draw/draw.page.ts#L71-L89 `isTransparent` would always be `false`, because you draw the stroke (line 84) at the same coordinate *before* calling `isTransparent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you will need a reference to the canvas, a reference to the drawing context of that canvas and choose when to update the percentage:

1) retrieve the canvas (for instance with [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('id_of_the_canvas');
```

2) retrieve the [drawing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

3) retrieve the [image data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) (all the image data)

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

4) decide at which point you consider a pixel transparent (transparency threshold) and compute the ratio between transparent and non transparent pixel, use [imageData.data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) for faster computation:

```
var pixelCount = canvas.width * canvas.height;
var arrayElemsCount = pixelCount * 4; // for components (rgba) per pixel.
var dataArray = imageData.data;
// 0 is completely transparent, set to 0.5 to
// allow for instance semi transparent pixels to be accounted for
var threshold = 0;
var transparentPixelCount = 0;
// remember fourth (index = 3) byte is alpha
for (var i = 3; i < arrayElemsCount; i+= 4) {
    var alphaValue = dataArray[i];
    if (alphaValue <= threshold) {
        transparentPixelCount++;
    }
}
var transparencyPercentage = (transparentPixelCount / pixelCount) * 100;
```

This operation is computationaly intensive so choose well when to execute it: either after some time ellapsed since the last drawing operation ([debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) during drawing) or at regular interval during drawing ([throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js) during drawing).

Comment: What if it is a linear gradient, not an image? in this case getImageData can't be used

Comment: The question has nothing to do with backgrounds or css coloring. It is specifically about canvas manipulation, on which you can always use getImageData.