# Javascript - in-process function executor with rate limiter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, throttling, rate-limiting

Imagine that I have some function `f()` which should be executed constantly. But I want to set a rate limit for execution, something like "Execute function no more than 10 times in 1 minute". In a code view I think it can have the following interface:

```
(async () => {
  const f = async () => {};
  const executor = new Executor({ max: 1, duration: 10000 });

  Array(10).fill(null).map(x => executor.addJob(f));

  await executor.execute();
})();
```

I have a few ideas about how to implement this on pure JS, but some implementations are already available? Also, I know that it's possible to implement with some 3-party soft, such as Bull queue and so on, but I need exactly in-process implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you seeking for is known as *throttling*. You can find it implemented in popular libraries like [lodash's throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) or you can implement it in vanilla javascript like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js) answer