# How to throttle a function which is called by `window.postMessage()` event

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events, throttling

I am working on an application where I am making different `window.postMessage()` requests to pass messages. When I listen to a message with `window.addEventListener('message', cb)` I call another function, but some times I receive multiple calls to the function because it depends on how many times I post the message. I created a simple throttle function, which works well, but not for function calls. For instance, let's say when three times the function is called within `1000ms`, the function should be called once and not three.

I am wondering this is the expected behavior, but in my case, the function is called three times.

I have used the throttle function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js), also [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tk5fLz8d/6/) is the example fiddle I have created to see what I mean.

```js
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
    var context, args, result;
    var timeout = null;
    var previous = 0;
    if (!options) options = {};
    var later = function () {
      previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
      timeout = null;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      if (!timeout) context = args = null;
    };
    return function () {
      var now = Date.now();
      if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
      var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
      context = this;
      args = arguments;
      if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
        if (timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = null;
        }
        previous = now;
        result = func.apply(context, args);
        if (!timeout) context = args = null;
      } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
        timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
      }
      return result;
    };
  }

  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener(
    "click",
    throttle(function () {
      console.log("BUTTON CLICKED");
    }, 1000)
  );

  window.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
    if (data.type === "viewer:clear:cache") {
      throttle(test(), 1000);
    }
  });

  function test() {
    console.log("TEST CALLED");
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    window.postMessage({ type: "viewer:clear:cache" }, "*");
  }
```

```html
    <button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: Throttle and debounce are two different things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function

Comment: Yes, I know. Am I using it somewhere ? @FelixKling

Comment: I just mentioned it because you tagged the question with debouncing, so I was confused to what behavior you are looking for. It seems totally possible that the function is called more than once, even with throttle, depending on how you've configured it. Please include the relevant code in your question. We cannot really offer a solution if we don't know what you are actually doing.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, that's the exact code fiddle that I created and shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how in the click handler case you are passing the return value of `throttle` to `addEventListener`. In the message event case you are calling `throttle` inside the event handler and ignore the return value.

You are also not passing a function to throttle but the *return value* of `test()`. I.e. you are calling `test` first and then pass `undefined` to `throttle`. That's why `test` is called every time the message event handler is called.

What you need is:

```
window.addEventListener("message", throttle(({ data }) => {
  if (data.type === "viewer:clear:cache") {
    test();
  }
}, 1000));
```

`throttle` returns a new function and it's *that* function that needs to be called upon receiving an event.