# Calling the function only once in a time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have such a function on my website:

```
$("#search-label").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
    }, 2000);   
  }
});
```

Its task is to scroll to the selected element after press enter and it works fine, but the problem is that it can be called repeatedly in a short time and then the page gets stuck.

How to limit the possibility of calling it up to once every 10 seconds?

Thanks

Comment: Search for "debouncing".

Comment: "use 10 seconds instead of 2 seconds" this is the rewind time, not the pause between calling the function

Comment: I think you are looking for throttling, I would recommend lodash's `throttle` function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle - or see this question for a solution with no dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-js

Comment: Why is `html` in the query selector? That seems rather backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mix of a variable and a `setTimeout` to do this:

```js
var scrollOK = true;

$("#search-label").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if((e.which == 13) && scrollOK) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
    }, 2000);   
    scrollOK = false;
    setTimeout(function(){ scrollOK=true; }, 10000);
  }
});
```

It uses `scrollOK` to make sure that scrolling is OK, and when it scrolls, then it sets it to `false` temporarily (temporarily because the `setTimeout` sets it back to `true` after 10 seconds, or 10000 milliseconds).

Edit: as @ChloeAnderson said, this may take up more resources than it should.  This is a version that should be better:

```js
var lastScrolled = 0;

$("#search-label").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if((e.which == 13) && (Date.now() >= (lastScrolled + 10000))) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
    }, 2000);   
    lastScrolled = Date.now();
  }
});
```

Comment: Please refrain from using intervals (or timeouts) for cooldowns, there's nothing wrong with using timestamps such as `performance.now()`, as they will only be evaluated upon request.

Comment: @ChloeAnderson: I don't understand what is wrong with using a `setTimeout`.  It seems perfect for this situation.

Comment: It seems, and may be, but a much more performance setting is to use timestamps. You're using more resources by relying on an interval than to compare two integers, being timestamps.

Comment: @ChloeAnderson: OK.  I added your solution in my question.  Thank you!