# Simulate a continues keystroke with a code in a Chrome

Tags: javascript, keystroke

I need ideas how to Simulate a continues keystroke with a code in a Chrome browser in a specific text field to simulate UP key button press with 10 sec wait time between each press

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple throttle in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-javascript)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.