# How do i stop my ajax call from loading the same result twice with excessive scrolling?

Tags: javascript, php

when someone would immediatly scroll to the bottom after loading the code it would sometimes not update the id on time and load the same query
heres my script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function() {
  if ((window.innerHeight + Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset)) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    var lastId = $(".postid:last").attr("id");
    var elem = document.getElementById("ele");
    setTimeout(() => {
        getMoreData(lastId);
        elem.scrollIntoView();
    }, 0);
  }
}

function getMoreData(lastId) {
       $(window).off("scroll");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'load_more.php?lastId=' + lastId,
        type: "get",
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
            $('.ajax-loader').show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
               setTimeout(function() {
                $('.ajax-loader').hide();
            $("#post-list").append(data);
               },1000);
        }
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) a sthe means by which to trigger fresh ajax calls? Also - in the js you reference `document.getElementById("ele");` is there more than one of these?

Comment: No theres only one

Comment: You can always create an array of id's that have already been loaded and if the `lastId` is in it, just give a return in the `getMoreData` function.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to *throttle* the ajax requests after scroll event (say no more than once per 250ms).

You may use this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59378445/3807365):

```js
function throttle(func, timeFrame) {
  var lastTime = 0;
  return function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now - lastTime >= timeFrame) {
      func();
      lastTime = now;
    }
  };
}

var count = 1;

var throttled = throttle(function() {
  console.log("doing ajax " + count++);
}, 250)
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttled)
```

```html
<body style="height: 4000px">
  keep scrolling no matter what
</body>
```

Comment: That still doesn't work for me but the double loading seems to happen when i scroll upwards after just loading something