# Perform an action every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make it possible to attack every second when clicking on space (between seconds the action must be impossible so that when holding the space bar the action does not occur in a loop).

I tried to prevent it with a state variable and with a setInterval, the state variable does not react as I want or I misunderstand and the setInterval just delays the spam of the space bar.

```
function moovePlayer() {
    //State to not start the animation while one is already in progress
    let state = false;
    let stateAttack = false;
    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (state == false) {
            state = true;
            //Retrieving player parent
            let parentPlayer = $('.player').parent();
            //Retrieving the player parent index 
            let indexParentPlayer = $('.block-x').index(parentPlayer);
            //Condition to know that it is touching is to press
            switch (e.code) {
                {...}//other code
                case 'Space':
                    //stateAttack is a state variable that prevents spamming the space hold attack
                    if (stateAttack == false) {
                        stateAttack = true;
                        
                        // let intervalAttack = setInterval(function () {

                        //Recovery of the 4 sides of the player
                        let block_x_up = $($('.block-x').eq(indexParentPlayer - number_block_y));
                        let block_x_down = $($('.block-x').eq(indexParentPlayer + number_block_y));
                        let block_x_right = $($('.block-x').eq(indexParentPlayer + 1));
                        let block_x_left = $($('.block-x').eq(indexParentPlayer - 1));


                        //Checking if enemy in the 4 sides recovered
                        if ((block_x_up.children().length > 0) || (block_x_down.children().length > 0) || (block_x_right.children().length > 0) || (block_x_left.children().length > 0)) {
                            
                            animateAttackRight();
                            //using the attack function
                            attack($('.player'), $('.enemy'));
                            // clearInterval(intervalAttack);
                            stateAttack = false
                        } else {
                            // clearInterval(intervalAttack);

                            state = false;
                            stateAttack = false

                        }
                        // }, 1000)

                    }
                    else {
                        // clearInterval(intervalAttack)
                        stateAttack = false;

                    }

                default:
                    state = false;


            }

        }

    })
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you are asking for is "throttling", which is covered in depth in a lot of questions, e.g. [Simple throttle in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078285/simple-throttle-in-javascript)

Comment: Store time when you "fire", then compare ticks between last fired and now, if less than limit, ignore/don't allow, otherwise fire and record new fire time.