# Event listener on className element, React Js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, event-handling

How about friends, I have an eventHandler added to a div that listens if the user scrolls to hide the navigation bar. It works fine since the container that performs the scroll function is the body, but if I add the overflow: scroll style to the div that contains my sections, the eventHandler doesn't work anymore. How can I add this same code to a div that contains the .layoutContainer class?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", handleScroll, {
      passive: true,
    });
  }, []);
```

I tried doing getElementByClassName but it didn´t works. Hope you can help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939886/find-first-scrollable-parent
function getScrollContainer(node) {
  while (node) {
    if (node.scrollHeight > node.clientHeight) {
      return node;
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return null;
}

// we want a reference to the current DOM node
const ref = React.useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  // determine what element is scrolling
  const container = getScrollContainer(ref.current);
  if(!container) return;

  // add the event listener
  container.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
  container.addEventListener("touchmove", handleScroll, { passive: true });

  return () => {
    // and clean up after yourself
    container.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    container.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleScroll);
  }
}, [/* sure that this doesn't rely on some dependency, like some `isVisible` state? */]);

// set the ref so we get access to the DOM node
return <div ref={ref} ...
```

And unless this component gets added, and later removed on `handleScroll`, I'm almost certain that your effect should be executed based on some dependent value, and not just on `componentDidMount`

Comment: Yeah thank you that works for sure i make it works and then saw your reply with this is the same way i did it, just need to use refs. Thank you so much

Comment: @JoangelDeLaRosa, don't forget to remove the event listener.