# Python selenium - How to access the inner scroll inside the main scroll

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, infinite-scroll

I am trying to scrape all the data in the website as shown in the image. [image: here] For that, I'll need to keep on scrolling down the infinite scroll. But I am unable to access the inner scroll. I use the following code for infinite scrolling

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

It doesn't work. It scrolls down the main outer scroll instead of the inner one, as shown below. Kindly help me scroll down the inner scroll

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1 You have to find the scrollable element.

Try some of this suggestions

[Find first scrollable parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939886/find-first-scrollable-parent)

2 And then

```
scrollable_element = driver.find_element... # locate using css or xpath the element, found during point 1 research

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", scrollable_element)
```