# Selenium Div Scroll

Tags: html, selenium, scroll

wen I apply the method Scroll to a whole window it works fine:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
```

The problem is that I must apply it to a DIV so I get the Div and then apply Scroll like this:

```
    myDiv = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"ODSEW-ShBeI NIyLF-haAclf gm2-body-2")]')
myDiv..execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")
```

but it do nothing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your div is scrollable, this should work:

```
myDiv = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"ODSEW-
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, 1000)", myDiv)
```

If the element is not scrollable:

```py
# thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35940276/5226491
find_scrollable_parent_script = '''
function getScrollParent(node) {
  if (node == null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (node.scrollHeight > node.clientHeight) {
    return node;
  } else {
    return getScrollParent(node.parentNode);
  }
}

return getScrollParent(arguments[0]);
'''
myDiv = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"ODSEW-ShBeI NIyLF-haAclf gm2-body-2")]')
scrollable = self.driver.execute_script(find_scrollable_parent_script, myDiv)
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, 1000)", scrollable)
```

Comment: Thank you, I get this error:Message: javascript error: arguments[0].scroll is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)

Comment: Sorry, my issue. In the first line should be `driver.find_element` instead of `driver.find_elements`

Comment: Now there is no error but no scroll. I guess the problem is that there are one div within other and other and so on.... There are like 20 and try all but no scroll at all. When I use it in a "flat" window it scrolls so not sure what the issue is. For sure you can scroll when in the site so it must be possible.

Comment: @bartoro I think scroll doesn't work because the element is not scrollable. So, try to find the first scrollable parent for this element `'//div[contains(@class,"ODSEW-ShBeI NIyLF-haAclf gm2-body-2")]'`.  This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35940276/5226491. You can invoke this function in browser console, or execute with webdriver (in this case you also have to pass `myDiv` to script like `arguments[0]` ).

Comment: @bartoro I've updated the answer again.