# IntersectionObserver - toggle a class when sticky element intersects with viewport + top property

Tags: javascript, observers

I wanted to add a class when the header was sticky but with a condition that it should not be with respect to viewport. It should be viewport plus some top ( css ) value. My sticky component is having a top property to adjust from where it will sticky with respect to viewport.

I tried many things such as changing rootMargin but was unsuccessful, some help would be appreciated

```
const stickyElm = document.querySelector('.automations-dashboard > div > span:nth-child(3)');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle('isSticky', e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  { rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px' }
);
if (stickyElm) observer.observe(stickyElm);
```

Reference SO - [Event to detect when position:sticky is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302483/event-to-detect-when-positionsticky-is-triggered)

Comment: Try to use this tip: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-detect-when-a-sticky-element-gets-pinned/ and working example

Comment: @Oleg Already saw this approach, but idk what changes should I make to add class when IntersectionObserver stick some px from the top rather than at the viewport

Comment: Did you read this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302483/event-to-detect-when-positionsticky-is-triggered