# Using position sticky with child flex elements causes flicker so using position fixed and Javascript scrollbar position instead

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I've got a navigation component that consists of a skinny banner (that should hide on toward scroll) and a main-nav that should then stick to top & and shrink.

I've followed the popular answer on using Intersection Observer:
[Event to detect when position:sticky is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302483/event-to-detect-when-positionsticky-is-triggered)

But the issue with that solution is that my child elements (flex) cause a flicker when going between the hidden and shown sticky banner. I can't remove those child elements for obvious reasons so instead I'm opting for a `position: fixed` on the `main-nav` with a `top: 40px`. This means the skinny-banner scrolls away as desired, but I need help getting the scrollbar position with Javascript, and then adding a class like (`.isSticky` when the skinny-banner is no longer there to ensure the main-nav sticks to the top).

```
.isSticky {
 top: 0;
 height: 66px;
}
```

```css
body { 
 margin: 0;
 height: 200vh;  
}

.skinny-banner{
  background: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.sticky-nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;                    


  background: salmon;
  transition: .1s;
}

/* styles for when the header is in sticky mode */
.sticky-nav.isSticky{
  top: 0;
  height: 66px;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="skinny-banner">Skinny banner that on scroll down disapears.</div>
   <div class="sticky-nav">Sticky Header that on scroll down sticks to top and shrinks in height when stuck</div>
</header>
```

I'm hoping to use a vanilla JS, HTML & CSS solution & want to maintain the HTML structure with a wrapping container with the skinny-banner and nav-menu as children.

Comment: I already gave you a duplicate in your previous question that solves your issue using only CSS

Comment: I outlined in the OP that this question required a different approach due to child elements flex properties causing a "flicker"

Comment: With jQuery you can easily check if a certain element is visible on the page or not: `$('your-element').is(':visible')`. With pure javascipt there are a few more steps involved hence why I mention jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems easier to set up a JavaScript listening to the scroll event on the window and updating the `isSticky` class accordingly based on the scroll position.

I also removed the transition, in case it participates in the flicker you see.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

.skinny-banner {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.sticky-nav {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 0 16px;
}


/* styles for when the header is in sticky mode */

.wrapper.isSticky .sticky-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 66px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper.isSticky .skinny-banner {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="skinny-banner">Skinny banner that on scroll down disappears.</div>
      <div class="sticky-nav">Sticky Header that on scroll down sticks to top and shrinks in height when stuck</div>
      <div>Test content 1</div>
      <div>Test content 2</div>
      <div>Test content 3</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
      const skinnyBanner = document.querySelector('.skinny-banner');
      let previousScrollY = window.scrollY;

      function updateSticky() {
        const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;

        if (currentScrollY > skinnyBanner.offsetHeight) {
          wrapper.classList.add('isSticky');
        } else {
          wrapper.classList.remove('isSticky');
        }

        previousScrollY = currentScrollY;
      }

      window.addEventListener('scroll', updateSticky);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To make sure the red banner `sticky-nav` should stick to the top even when scrolling up, the `isSticky` class is added to the wrapper element as soon as the user scrolls past the height of the skinny`-banner`, making the `sticky-nav` stick to the top regardless of the scroll direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the solution ignores the requirement of having a wrapping div of which the  `skinny-banner` & `sticky-nav` are child elements.

Comment: @cts True. I have edited the answer to include a wrapping `div` of which the `skinny-banner` & `sticky-nav` are child elements.

Comment: thanks for your reply and making the update. Sadly when you scroll to the bottom of the viewport, and then scroll back up, the `sticky-nav` is not visible.

Comment: @cts When I scroll back up, I confirm the sticky-nav is visible. Both are.

Comment: The `sticky-nav` should be visible at all times.

Comment: @cts I confirm, the `sticky-nav` (the red banner with the "Sticky Header that on scroll down sticks to top and shrinks in height when stuck" in it) is visible at all times.

Comment: Having tried it both in the Stack Overflow snippet & a seperate codepen, my experience is that on scroll down: the skinny banner disappears, the sticky-nav increases in size, but once at the bottom of the viewport, and then scrolling up, neither are visible until both become visible at the non-sticky heights.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253531/discussion-between-vonc-and-cts).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for `.sticky-nav` fails to get sticky is because it is inside of the `<header>` element. That element has a default `display: block` according to [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php#:%7E:text=header). So it will block the sticky behavior for its child elements (include `position: sticky`). To get this done, you should set the `display: initial` for the `<header>` element.

You can also detect when the element gets sticky with the value of `.offsetTop`. The value will change if the element gets sticky. But, before you should specify `position: sticky` and `top: 0` for `.sticky-nav`.

```js
const stickyNav = document.querySelector('.sticky-nav');
const initalPos = stickyNav.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if(stickyNav.offsetTop > initalPos) {
    stickyNav.classList.add('isSticky');
  } else {
    stickyNav.classList.remove('isSticky');
  }
});
```

```css
body { 
 margin: 0;
 height: 200vh;  
}
header{
  display: initial;
}
.skinny-banner{
  background: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.sticky-nav{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: salmon;
  min-height: 1px; /* custom this */
  transition: min-height ease 1s; /* custom this */
}

/* styles for when the header is in sticky mode */
.sticky-nav.isSticky{
  top: 0;
  min-height: 66px;  /* custom this */
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="skinny-banner">Skinny banner that, on scroll down, disappears.</div>
   <div class="sticky-nav">Sticky Header that, on scroll down, sticks to top and shrinks in height when stuck</div>
   <div>Test content 1</div>
   <div>Test content 2</div>
   <div>Test content 3</div>
   <div>Test content 4</div>
   <div>Test content 5</div>
   <div>Test content 6</div>
   <div>Test content 7</div>
   <div>Test content 8</div>
   <div>Test content 9</div>
   <div>Test content 10</div>
   <div>Test content 11</div>
   <div>Test content 12</div>
   <div>Test content 13</div>
   <div>Test content 14</div>
   <div>Test content 15</div>
   <div>Test content 16</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Jordy, thanks for this: it's exactly how I'd want it to behave. One question: when there is other content on the same level as `Header` - the flicker is visible again? https://jsfiddle.net/98ecm7s0/35/

Comment: @cts You're welcome. Flicker behavior can be solved with `min-height` as stated in the updated answer above.

Comment: I think this circles back to the issue outlined in the OP: using `sticky` in this way only works if the child elements don't use flex, otherwise: we have the infamous "flicker": https://jsfiddle.net/98ecm7s0/37/

Comment: Not to worry anyway, the answer below is complete. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @cts You're welcome, then give the check mark if you satisfied.

Comment: Nice: that seems simpler than my answer, and preserve the transition effect. (I set it to 1 second just to better see said transition: it looks cool!)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your experience and insights! Please try out the following solution that might be helpful.

```js
  window.onscroll = function() {stickyNav()};

  function stickyNav() {
    let navbar = document.querySelector(".sticky-nav");
    let banner = document.querySelector(".skinny-banner");      
    let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("isSticky");
  banner.classList.add("hide-banner"); 

    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("isSticky");
      banner.classList.remove("hide-banner");
    }
  }
```

```css
    body { 
      margin: 0;
      height: 200vh;  
    }

    .skinny-banner {
      background: lightblue;
      height: 40px;
      display: flex;
    }

    .nav-menu {
      display: flex;
    }

    .sticky-nav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      background: salmon;
      transition: .1s;
    }

    /* styles for when the header is in sticky mode */
    .sticky-nav.isSticky {
      top: 0;
      height: 77px;
    }

    .hide-banner {
    display: none;
     }

    div {
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="sticky-nav">Sticky Header that on scroll down sticks to top and shrinks in height when stuck</div>
<div class="skinny-banner">Skinny banner that on scroll down disapears.</div>      
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
```