# Using offsetTop property to create sticky header behaviour on navigation component

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, offset

I've been battling with an issue for several days now and can't manage to arrive at a working solution.

The component is a header that includes a skinny-banner and a sticky-nav that are wrapped in a parent element (so component level properties can be passed to it).

I'm using vanilla HTML, CSS & Javascript only and have tried various commonly accepted solutions but to no avail.

Skinny banner: should hide on scroll down

Sticky nav: should stick to top (when skinny banner is hidden), always remain visible and increase in height (when skinny banner is hidden).

I've currently got an open bounty for a different approach, but thus far no suitable answers have been put forward: [Using position sticky with child flex elements causes flicker so using position fixed and Javascript scrollbar position instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183858/using-position-sticky-with-child-flex-elements-causes-flicker-so-using-position)

The common approach uses `sticky` but doesn't account for child elements using `display: flex`.

In this snippet I am trying to use `offsetTop` to add a `fixed` class when the user scrolls away from the top of the viewport, but still not achieving the desired outcome.

```js
      var sticky = document.querySelector('.sticky-nav');
      var origOffsetY = sticky.offsetTop;

      function onScroll(e) {
        window.scrollY >= origOffsetY
          ? sticky.classList.add('fixed')
          : sticky.classList.remove('fixed');
      }
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.skinny-banner {
  background-color: lightpink;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

skinny-banner ul {
  display: flex;
}

.sticky-nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}

.nav-content {
  display: flex;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="skinny-banner">
    Skinny banner should disapear on scroll down
    <ul>
      Nav items
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sticky-nav">
    Sticky nav should stick to top and increase in height when skinny banner is
    hidden
    <div class="nav-content"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Any advice would be really welcome!

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something, but why change the position of sticky-nav to 'fixed' on scroll, instead of having the whole header 'fixed' in the first place?