# keep the background image fixed position and centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my project, I need to show a small image in **center of the visible part of the container, with respect to the window** i.e `.loader`. Even when the user scrolls the page, the image should be visible in center of `.loader`.

I successfully implemented this  but now I am facing a edgecase which is when user scrolls the page "up to the header" or "down to the footer", the small image is hiding.  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Ezhb4/2/show/).

This is actually normal behaviour but  in these edgecases, I want the image to stick to **top/bottom end** of the `.loader` container.

What I want:

- Keep the small image always at center of `.loader` container. (*I already implemented this*)
- when scrolled to **any end of `.loader` container**, the image should stick to that end instead of hiding behind the container.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Ezhb4/2/)

A solution using just css is preferred. I am looking for browser support in IE9+, chrome and firefox.

```css
.header {
    height: 600px;
    width: 650px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.left-side {
    height: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
.loader {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/U2njI.jpg');
    margin-left: 150px;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-position: 345px center;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.footer {
    height: 600px;
    width: 650px;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="left-side"></div>
<div class="loader"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, if only me that couldn't understand the problem.

Comment: @C-link I added some more explanation. please let me know if you still can't understand.

Comment: you should use jquery!

Comment: @Mr_Green - this is what position:sticky will be good for. See [here](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646747/css-position-sticky) and (then) [here] (http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/msUP9/) - if you enabled the flag

Comment: @Danield thank you for this cool info. I hope this will be helpful for future users. :) btw that flag is now changed as the chrome engine is upgraded to blink. [link](http://www.chromium.org/blink/runtime-enabled-features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution with javascript, I hope its behaviour is how you expect it to be. I'm unfortunately not able to test it on IE9 right now but it should work ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezhb4/15/show/)):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    var loader = document.querySelector('.loader'),
        loaderRect = loader.getBoundingClientRect(),
        loaderTop = loaderRect.top + document.body.scrollTop,
        loaderBottom = loaderTop + loader.offsetHeight,
        initialBgPos = loader.style.backgroundPosition,
        imageHeight = 141;

    function onScroll() {
        var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

        if(loaderTop >= (scrollTop + (window.innerHeight - imageHeight)/2)) {
            loader.style.backgroundPosition='345px ' + (loaderTop - scrollTop) + 'px'; 
        } else if(loaderBottom <= (scrollTop + (window.innerHeight + imageHeight)/2)) {
            loader.style.backgroundPosition='345px ' + (loaderBottom - scrollTop - imageHeight) + 'px'; 
        } else {
           loader.style.backgroundPosition = initialBgPos;
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    onScroll();    
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much.. somehow I didn't get ping for your answer.. I revisited my post to ask for bounty and found your solution.. I take that it is not possible with only css though.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what I think you want. We have to set the position of the *.loader* div to fixed, then it'll always stay where it's placed, regardless of whether the user scrolls the page, the div will scroll too. In here's how to set the position of loader to fixed in CSS (you may also have to get the position of your fixed div):

```
.loader{
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
    top: 300px;
 }
```

Here's your upadted JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ezhb4/4/

Comment: Xanco, where is the main container? I mean `.loader`.

Comment: It may not appear due to the JSFiddle results window being so small, try this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ezhb4/4/show/

Comment: It should appear, it is the main container in my project.

Comment: Is there any other HTML/CSS that you didn't include in your JSFiddle? It works fine over here: http://postimg.org/image/enljqw9ah/ I've commented out the background color, in the CSS, in case you were wondering