# Parallax Footer Is Visible In Between Header and Content

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have a one page design that is essentially

Header 
Content 
Footer

This page uses parallax and everything works the way I want it to but I see a small sliver of the footer in between the header and content. I am not sure why this is the case. I am not that efficient with code and just trying to learn and experiment. Here is my code.

HTML

```
    <body>
    <header class="alaska-box">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="hiker"></div>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      <article>
        <h1>Summer Collection</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>This is our summer collection, for the real inner survivor in you. This summer collection has a stealth theme for you.
        This is a great series of apparel and accesories to help you travel <strong>INTO THE WILD</strong>. </p>
        <hr>

        <div class="summer-collection">
          <ul class="product-grid">
            <li><img src="assets/collection/jacket.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Jacket" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Jacket <strong>$120</strong>
            </p></li><!--

            --><li><img src="assets/collection/shorts.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Shorts" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Jacket <strong>$120</strong>
            </p></li><!--
            --><li><img src="assets/collection/hat.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Hat" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Hat <strong>$60</strong>
            </p></li>
            <li><img src="assets/collection/backpack.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Backpack" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Backpack <strong>$235</strong>
            </p></li><!--
            --><li><img src="assets/collection/boot.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Boot" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Boot <strong>$100</strong>
            </p></li><!--
            --><li><img src="assets/collection/gloves.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Gloves" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Gloves <strong>$45</strong>
            </p></li>
            <li><img src="assets/collection/hammock.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Hammock" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Hammock <strong>$175</strong>
            </p></li><!--
            --><li><img src="assets/collection/tent.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Tent" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Tent <strong>$290</strong>
            </p></li><!--
            --><li><img src="assets/collection/knife.jpg" alt="Summer Collection Knife" /><p class="caption">
              Into the Wild Knife <strong>$75</strong>
            </p></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <h1>Summer Collection</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>This is our summer collection, for the real inner survivor in you. This summer collection has a stealth theme for you.
        This is a great series of apparel and accesories to help you travel <strong>INTO THE WILD</strong>. </p>
        <hr>

        <div class="large-window">
          <div class="window-tint">
            <div class="summer-promo"> Summer Collection <strong>$1,000</strong><a href="" class="window-cta">Buy Now</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h1>Our History</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>This is our summer collection, for the real inner survivor in you. This summer collection has a stealth theme for you.
        This is a great series of apparel and accesories to help you travel <strong>INTO THE WILD</strong>. </p>

      </article>
      </div>

    </div>
      <footer>
        <div class="footer-stuff">
          <div class="columns three b">
            <strong>FIND US ON!</strong>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Instagram</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="columns three">
            <strong>CHRIS MCCANDLESS</strong>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
              sed do eiusmod tempor
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="columns six">
            <p>
              <strong>GET DISCOUNTS</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </p>
            <form class="row">
              <div class="columns eight">
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="u-full-width">
              </div>
              <div class="four columns">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
     /* Base */

  body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  }

  h1 {
    color: #e5cb22;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  article {
    max-width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2
  }

  /* Parralax Stuff */

  .alaska-box {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(assets/header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px
    right: -8px;
    z-index: 3;
  }

  .logo {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(assets/logo-1.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }

  .hiker {
    width: 416px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url(assets/hiker.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right, bottom;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
  }

  /*Product Grid*/

  .summer-collection {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    top: auto;
  }

  .caption {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: -100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

  .summer-collection li:hover p {
    left: 0%; }

  .summer-collection li.is-showing {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0px);
  }

  .summer-collection li img {
      display: block;
      transform: scale(1);
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

  }

  .summer-collection li:hover img {
      transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .is-showing {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }

  .summer-collection li{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .product-grid {
    padding: 0;
  }

  ul.product.grid {
    display: inline-table;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: -2.5%;
  }

  ul.product-grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30.83%;
    margin: 1%;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  ul.product-grid li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
  }

  /*Media Queries for Grid*/

  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    ul.grid-nav li {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 0 5px;
    }

    ul.grid-nav li a {
      display: block;
    }

    ul.product-grid {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    ul.product-grid li {
      width: 100% !important;
      margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
  }

/*Periscope*/

  .large-window {
    height: 640px;
    background-image: url(assets/collection/large-window-img.jpg);
    background-position: top;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
  }

  .window-tint {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .summer-promo {
    color: #e5cb22;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }

  .window-cta {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e5cb22;
    border: 2px solid #e5cb22;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: 3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out, color 0.2s ease-out;
  }

  .window-cta:hover{
    background-color: #e5cb22;
    color: white;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in, color 0.3s ease-in;

  }

  .summer-promo strong {
    display: block;
    font-size: 40px;
  }

/* Footer */

footer {
background: black;
color: white;
padding: 20px 0;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1; }
footer .footer-stuff {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
footer a {
  color: white; }
footer input {
  color: #666; }
```

Comment: 1) You have an extra closing `<div>` tag before your footer. 2) Your footer is set to `position: fixed;` meaning it's at the same spot on your screen no matter where you scroll. You *can* make a site this way, but you'll need to make sure there's no space between your header and your body on any resolution, so that it's hidden.

Comment: What is an alternative to the position? Relative? Also how do I make sure there is not space in between? I am not sure what is causing the space to be there?

Comment: You can use relative, but you can also use fixed. Do a google search for how to build a page with a fixed footer. But what I think you're looking for is really `position: sticky;` behavior which [doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646747/why-doesnt-position-sticky-work-in-chrome/26222260#26222260) in most browsers yet in CSS. You can use a JS library to polyfill that feature. Do a google search for how to build a page with a fixed/sticky footer, and then go from there.

Comment: Basically you need to get the page setup correctly while it's static, and then you can add in the parallax effect of two objects at different distances moving at different speeds relative to the user.

Comment: Will fixed still give the parallax affect?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't worked with parallax effects in some time.